# what is a virtual method in c++?

Tags: c++

what is a virtual method in c++?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat; I agree with you, since such a fundamental question should be researched instead of being asked casually, especially with no context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain C++ Virtual Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/can-someone-explain-c-virtual-methods)

Comment: In c++ "methods" are called "member functions".  This can help you search for what they are.

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate, but it most certainly is a real question.  And people who flagged it as 'not a real question' should be ashamed of themselves.  I think beginner level questions are much more important than the sorts of questions that end up with really high ratings here, and this is just such a question.  Calling it 'not a real question' is a form of name calling.  You're basically declaring the OP to be stupid.

Comment: This question should probably have been closed as "exact duplicate" rather than "not a real question".  Clearly, it is a real question.  A question that no doubt has already been asked and answered satisfactorily on this site.

Comment: C++ has no virtual methods. Everything is written actually. The only virtual method maybe is that they communicate with mailing lists mostly.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, as Don Roby noted, but I consider it a valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A virtual function allows derived classes to replace the implementation provided by the base class. The compiler makes sure the replacement is always called whenever the object in question is actually of the derived class, even if the object is accessed by a base pointer rather than a derived pointer. This allows algorithms in the base class to be replaced in the derived class, even if users don't know about the derived class.

The derived class can either fully replace ("override") the base class member function, or the derived class can partially replace ("augment") the base class member function. The latter is accomplished by having the derived class member function call the base class member function, if desired.

Learn more here:

http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorials/c-virtual-function.aspx

However, this is very basic. Try google next time before coming here to ask!

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html) were invented so you don't have to switch over types.

Answer (score 0):

It is a method that is looked up at runtime instead of compile-time. This allows things such as polymorphism to work.

Comment: vtables are an implementation detail. The C++ standard does not say anything about "vtables".

Comment: @FredOverflow: Out of curiosity, which implementations don't use a vtable?

Comment: Most practical implementations do tend to use a vtable, at least as far as I'm aware. But Fred is making a valid point - the question asks what a virtual method is in C++, where C++ is the language as defined by its standard. The fact that the implementation might use a vtable is interesting, but it's not a direct answer to the question as stated.