# Why doesn't this code cast a base class into a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't this c++ code work? It is meant to dynamically cast a base class into a derived class. How would I achieve this?

```
    class base {
    public:
        int x = 0;
    };

    class a : public base {
    public:
        char c = 'a';
    };

    class b : public base {
    public:
        long int d = 'b';
    };

    std::vector<base> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        b temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        b* temp = (b*)&vec[i];
        std::cout << temp->d << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Read up on [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). I'm tempted to call it a duplicate of that post even.

Comment: I believe that it undefined behavior. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @Chipster `std::vector<base>` stores elements of type `base`. Reinterprete cast to `b` is for sure U.B. ;-)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It's more like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14914940/10957435) instead, but yours is also close.

Comment: Think IS A and HAS A, inheritance vs composition.

Comment: Object Slicing is not the problem. He needs to have vector of pointer to Base.

Comment: @abhiarora - And did you not stop to consider *why* only pointers work here? Of course slicing is the problem.

Comment: What you are trying to do? Inheritance basically is used to access base class properties into the derived class.

Comment: You must hold pointers to base in your vector for polymorphism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you push an object of `b` into vector `vec` of `Base` Objects, you create another object from `temp` which is purely of type `base`. You might be thinking (and you are not right!) that element which is being stored in `vector` will be of type Base but it will be holding an object of type `b`but it's not how you achieve `Dynamic Polymorphism` in C++.

The statements:

```
std::vector<Base> vec; // 1
b temp;                // 2
vec.push_back(temp);   // 3
```

The third line will create a different object to type `Base` by calling assignment operator of base class `Base operator=(const Base& )`.

Also,`b* temp = (b*)&vec[i];` is an undefined behavior because you are explicitly trying to cast a pointer to object of `base` to it's derived class type `b` but it doesn't hold object of type `b` and hence, you may get unexpected behavior.

**NOTE:**

Use [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) for casting between base and derived class as it will make sure that the conversion is valid. Otherwise, it will return `nullptr`. However, you need to make your base class polymorphic by having at least 1 [virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824359/why-use-virtual-functions).

> If the cast is successful, dynamic_cast returns a value of type new-type. If the cast fails and new-type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new-type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast.

**SOLUTION:**

Use vector of pointers to `base` class to achieve run-time polymorphism.

```
std::vector<base *> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    b *temp = new b();
    vec.push_back(temp);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    b* temp = dynamic_cast<b *>(vec[i]); // For dynamic cast, you need to add virtual functions to your base class
    if (temp != nullptr)
        std::cout << temp->d << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT:**

<s>Object Slicing is also a solution for your problem</s>. `Object Slicing` is the right keyword for this type of problems. Here is the [definition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/) of the Object Slicing

> Object slicing happens when a derived class object is assigned to a base class object, additional attributes of a derived class object are sliced off to form the base class object.

I am quoting one of the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) below. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14461532/5735010) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403759/5735010) for the best explanation and possible solution with some code snippet. See this [article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/12-8-object-slicing/), it has explained the problem when pushing object of Derived class in a vector of base class.

> "Slicing" is where you assign an object of a derived class to an instance of a base class, thereby losing part of the information - some of it is "sliced" away.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> class A {
>    int foo;
> };
>
> class B : public A {
>    int bar;
> };
> ```
>
> So an object of type B has two data members, foo and bar.
>
> Then if you were to write this:
>
> ```
> B b;
> A a = b;
> ```
>
> Then the information in b about member bar is lost in a.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by **object slicing**. You expect `base` to be a **reference type**, like it would be in C# or Java, but in fact, it's a **value type** in C++.

[Reference vs value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types):

> There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types. Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data.

What actually happens in your code: You push an instance of `b` to a `vector<base>`. Since class `b` is not a class `base`, a new instance of `base` will be created in the vector using the implicitly generated copy constructor, but only the base portion of the `b` instance will be copied, hence "slicing down" the member `d` from the `b` instance.

The solution is to store **pointers** to `base`. So, in your case the vector should store raw (`base*`) or managed (`unique_ptr<base>` or `shared_ptr<base>`) pointers (prefer managed pointers to raw ones). It works, because it doesn't matter if you refer to an instance of `b` in memory through a `b*` or a `base*`, it still point to the same `b` object.

```cpp
#include <iostream> // endl, cout
#include <memory> // make_unique, unique_ptr
#include <vector> // vector

class base {
public:
    int x = 0;
};

class a : public base {
public:
    char c = 'a';
};

class b : public base {
public:
    long int d = 'b';
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        vec.push_back(std::make_unique<b>());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const b* temp = static_cast<const b*>(vec[i].get());
        std::cout << temp->d << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Side note:** You used C-style cast (`(b*)`), I changed it to `static_cast`, a better solution would be to use `dynamic_cast`, but that cannot be used in this case because your base class is not polymorphic (you need at least 1 virtual function for that).