# Using base class function with derived class values

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I'm having problems getting a vector of objects to print the name of the derived class rather then the base class.

These are my classes

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Object
{
    string name;
public:
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class Flashlight : public Object
{
    string name = "Flashlight";
public:
    string getName();
};
```

This is my main, it has a vector of the objects and at this point just needs to print out their names.

```
int main()
{
    vector<Object> items;
    items.push_back(*new Flashlight);

    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << " " << items.at(i).getName();
    }
}
```

Right now if I assign something to the name in Object it will print that but its not using the derived classes values, I just want it to inherit the function then use its own values with it. I've tried implementing the function in the base classes(but seeing as I could have a lot of those in future it would lead to lots of redundant code) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to have vector of pointers

Comment: Your code suffers from object slicing. Because you have a `vector<Object>`, any `Flashlight` is *sliced* to an Object when you add it to your vector. You need a `vector<Object*>`. There are other issues with your code but I guess they're just attempts to correct what is the fundmental error of object slicing.

Comment: @john: The attempt at overriding member variable is just as serious problem. Both have to be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Object *> items;
    items.push_back(new Flashlight);

    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << " " << items.at(i)->getName();
    }
}
```

Also as mentioned in another answer it would be good to use `virtual` methods read about it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/can-someone-explain-c-virtual-methods)

What is more you need to use constructor to set value for variable `name`. You can read about them [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/constructor_destructor_ordering.html)

You should try this way:

```
class Object
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    Object() : name("Object")
    {}
    Object(string str) : name(str)
    {}

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class Flashlight : public Object
{
public:
    Flashlight() : Object("Flashlight")
    {}

    string getName();
};
```

Comment: This is only part of the problem. The variable is still not initialized properly.

Comment: Yeah this worked, I tried using pointers earlier but was using them wrong, thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2861504 If it was really helpful you should accept an answer. That is how SO system works

Answer (score 3):

Instead of declaring variable 'name' in derived classes, initialize the variables value as custom value for that derived class. Also I would suggest you to make getName method as virtual. You also do not need to override getName method in derived classes if you just want to output name.

Comment: This is only part of the problem. The collection is of Object, not of flashlights.

Comment: What if you do not redefine name variable in derived class and  initialize the value of name (defined in base) in derived class using constructor/setter or something.

Comment: That's what you should be doing, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems:

1. `getName()` is not virtual. This means that the actual function called is decided at compile time, based on the variable *static* type. So, if your variable is of type `Object`, `Object&` or `Object*` (or any `const` variation on those), function `Object::getName()` will be called, regardless of the actual type of the object referred to or pointed to by your variable (the *dynamic* type).
2. You have a `vector<Object>`, which means that all objects stored in it are of type `Object`. You can try to put a `Flashlight` object in it, but only the `Object` part will be copied into the vector. If you need polymorphism in a `vector<>`, you need a vector of pointers (or even better, smart pointers).

So you have to do two things to get the desired behaviour:

1. Declare function `getName()` as `virtual string getName()` (even
   better, `virtual const string& getName() const`)
2. Declare `items` as `vector<Object*> items` (even better, use an
   appropriate smart pointer such as `unique_ptr<>` instead of a raw
   pointer)