# Not Understanding Polymorphic Functions

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I am trying to create an array of objects whose class' all inherit from a Base class. Since I am just learning C++ after using Python, this was my first encounter with object slicing. From what I have read I should use pointers to the objects instead of instances of the objects themselves, but I can't seem to make it work.

For example, why does this program output:
1
1
instead of:
1
2

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    int getNumber(){
        return(1);
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    int getNumber(){
        return(2);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A* list[2];
    list[0] = new A();
    list[1] = new B();

    std::cout << list[0]->getNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << list[1]->getNumber() << std::endl;

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which C++ book are you using? This is definitely covered in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, and you seem to understand object slicing just fine. However, object slicing is not taking place here — it's the function calls themselves that are giving you grief.

**You need to mark your member functions as `virtual` in order to take advantage of polymorphism.**

<sup>(More accurately, in order to take advantage of virtual dispatch.)</sup>

---

```
class A{
public:
    virtual int getNumber(){  // <--- `virtual`!
        return(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes my issue. Since the title of this is now misleading for anyone with a similar issue, should I rename/retag it?

Comment: @Giewev: I was wondering about that. Usually I'd say "no" but, in this instance, changing the title to say that you're not getting polymorphism in function calls when you expected it, might be better.

Answer (score 0):

You are not experiencing object slicing here.  This is an example of [function hiding](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/35681/).

Basically, since `A` and `B` both have a function `getNumber`, but it is not a virtual function, there is no virtual function table to tell the compiler which function should be called.  Instead, it will call the appropriate function based on the type (in this case, `A*`).

Declare `getNumber` as virtual in `A`, and this fixes your problem:  `virtual int getNumber() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The program is outputting `1 1` because the `getNumber` function is not marked as *`virtual`*.  Without the `virtual` keyword, the `A*` which points to a `B` doesn't know to look the function up in a v-table. So it just calls the `getNumber` function of `A`.

Declare the function as

```
virtual int getNumber( );
```

and you should get the expected behaviour.

Read more about [virtual functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/can-someone-explain-c-virtual-methods).