# Understanding Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to learn C++, and wrote this code. According to my understaing this code need to produce output as `"Derived Class"` but output is `"Base Class"`.
Please help me understand this.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Base { 
    public: 
    char* name; 
    void display() { 
         cout << name << endl; 
    }
```

};

```
class Derived: public Base { 
   public: 
   char* name; 
   void display() { 
       cout << name << ", " << Base::name << endl; 
   } 
}; 

int main() { 
   Derived d; 
   d.name = "Derived Class"; 
   d.Base::name = "Base Class"; 

   Derived* dptr = &d; 

   Base* bptr = dptr; 

   bptr->display();
}
```

Please consider me as a beginner and explain why its output is `"Base Class"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `display()` method `virtual`

Like this:

```
class Base{ 
    public: 
    char* name; 
    virtual void display() { 
         cout << name << endl; 
 }
```

`virtual` allows derived classes to 'override' the base class' functions.

Comment: @andy.. After making it virtual its output is "Derived Class Base Class"...but I am expecting only "Derived Class"

Comment: @someone: And why shouldn't it? You wrote `cout << name << ", " << Base::name << endl; ` not `cout << name << endl`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dyn-binding.html

> Non-virtual member functions are resolved statically. That is, the
>   member function is selected statically (at compile-time) based on the
>   type of the pointer (or reference) to the object.
>
> In contrast, virtual member functions are resolved dynamically (at
>   run-time). That is, the member function is selected dynamically (at
>   run-time) based on the type of the object, not the type of the
>   pointer/reference to that object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a derived class function to be called through a base class pointer, you need to make the base class function a virtual function. Add the key word virtual to the function and your code will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

C++ dispatch is little bit weird.   Unless you declare the display method 'virtual'  the bptr->display would alway call the display of base class.

More detailed explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/can-someone-explain-c-virtual-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism (working generically with base class pointers pointing to instances of derived classes) is done by dispatching to virtual functions as explained in the other answers.  However, if you point to a derived class with a base class pointer, you will use the data members of the base class because the compiler doesn't know the data members of the derived class and same goes for calling functions of the base class, so the base class `display()` function uses the base class `name` data member and you result is "Base Class".