# Is key-value observation (KVO) available in Swift?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

If so, are there any key differences that weren't otherwise present when using key-value observation in Objective-C?

Comment: An example project that demonstrates KVO being used in a UIKit interface via Swift:
https://github.com/jameswomack/kvo-in-swift

Comment: @JanDvorak See the [KVO Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA), which is a nice introduction to the topic.

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, you can also start actions using the didset() function.

Comment: Note there is a Swift4 **bug** when you use `.initial`. For a solution see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438532/5175709). I highly recommend to see [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift). It's been updated recently and covers lots of important notes. Also see Rob's [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40143264/5175709)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

(Edited to add new info): consider whether using the Combine framework can help you accomplish what you wanted, rather than using KVO

Yes and no. KVO works on NSObject subclasses much as it always has. It does not work for classes that don't subclass NSObject. Swift does not (currently at least) have its own native observation system.

(See comments for how to expose other properties as ObjC so KVO works on them)

See the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8) for a full example.

Comment: FYI, I filed a bug report with Apple about this. I encourage everyone else who would like to see a KVO or similar observation system in swift, to do the same.

Comment: Since Xcode 6 beta 5 you can use the `dynamic` keyword on any Swift class to enable KVO support.

Comment: Hooray for @fabb! For clarity, the `dynamic` keyword goes on the property that you want to make key-value-observable.

Comment: The explanation for the `dynamic` keyword can be find in the Apple Developer Library's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C section](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8).

Comment: Since this wasn't clear to me from @fabb's comment: use the `dynamic` keyword for any *properties* inside of a class you'd like to be KVO compliant (not the `dynamic` keyword on the class itself). This worked for me!

Comment: Can we say that `didSet` as KVO—to some extent?

Comment: Not really; you can't register a new didSet from the "outside", it has to be part of that type at compile time.

Comment: In Swift 5.1 it appears that you can't get KVO support by simply adding `dynamic` to the property declaration; you must specify `@objc dynamic`. Omitting the `@objc` will result in a `NSUnknownKeyException` when you call `value(forKey:)`.

Answer (score 163):

You can use KVO in Swift, but only for `dynamic` properties of `NSObject` subclass. Consider that you wanted to observe the `bar` property of a `Foo` class. In Swift 4, specify `bar` as `dynamic` property in your `NSObject` subclass:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var bar = 0
}
```

You can then register to observe changes to the `bar` property. In Swift 4 and Swift 3.2, this has been greatly simplified, as outlined in [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift):

```
class MyObject {
    private var token: NSKeyValueObservation

    var objectToObserve = Foo()

    init() {
        token = objectToObserve.observe(\.bar) { [weak self] object, change in  // the `[weak self]` is to avoid strong reference cycle; obviously, if you don't reference `self` in the closure, then `[weak self]` is not needed
            print("bar property is now \(object.bar)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note, in Swift 4, we now have strong typing of keypaths using the backslash character (the `\.bar` is the keypath for the `bar` property of the object being observed). Also, because it's using the completion closure pattern, we don't have to manually remove observers (when the `token` falls out of scope, the observer is removed for us) nor do we have to worry about calling the `super` implementation if the key doesn't match. The closure is called only when this particular observer is invoked. For more information, see WWDC 2017 video, [What's New in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/).

In Swift 3, to observe this, it's a bit more complicated, but very similar to what one does in Objective-C. Namely, you would implement `observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath:, of object:, change:, context:)` which (a) makes sure we're dealing with our context (and not something that our `super` instance had registered to observe); and then (b) either handle it or pass it on to the `super` implementation, as necessary. And make sure to remove yourself as an observer when appropriate. For example, you might remove the observer when it is deallocated:

In Swift 3:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    private var observerContext = 0

    var objectToObserve = Foo()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        objectToObserve.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Foo.bar), options: [.new, .old], context: &observerContext)
    }

    deinit {
        objectToObserve.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Foo.bar), context: &observerContext)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &observerContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }

        // do something upon notification of the observed object

        print("\(keyPath): \(change?[.newKey])")
    }

}
```

Note, you can only observe properties that can be represented in Objective-C. Thus, you cannot observe generics, Swift `struct` types, Swift `enum` types, etc.

For a discussion of the Swift 2 implementation, see my original answer, below.

---

Using the `dynamic` keyword to achieve KVO with `NSObject` subclasses is described in the *Key-Value Observing* section of the [Adopting Cocoa Design Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_5) chapter of the *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* guide:

> Key-value observing is a mechanism that allows objects to be notified of changes to specified properties of other objects. You can use key-value observing with a Swift class, as long as the class inherits from the `NSObject` class. You can use these three steps to implement key-value observing in Swift.
>
> 1. Add the `dynamic` modifier to any property you want to observe. For more information on `dynamic`, see [Requiring Dynamic Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_38).
>
>    ```
>    class MyObjectToObserve: NSObject {
>        dynamic var myDate = NSDate()
>        func updateDate() {
>            myDate = NSDate()
>        }
>    }
>    ```
> 2. Create a global context variable.
>
>    ```
>    private var myContext = 0
>    ```
> 3. Add an observer for the key-path, and override the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method, and remove the observer in `deinit`.
>
>    ```
>    class MyObserver: NSObject {
>        var objectToObserve = MyObjectToObserve()
>        override init() {
>            super.init()
>            objectToObserve.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myDate", options: .New, context: &myContext)
>        }
>
>        override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
>            if context == &myContext {
>                if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
>                    print("Date changed: \(newValue)")
>                }
>            } else {
>                super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
>            }
>        }
>
>        deinit {
>            objectToObserve.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myDate", context: &myContext)
>        }
>    }
>    ```

[Note, this KVO discussion has subsequently been removed from the *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* guide, which has been adapted for Swift 3, but it still works as outlined at the top of this answer.]

---

It's worth noting that Swift has its own native [property observer](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID262) system, but that's for a class specifying its own code that will be performed upon observation of its own properties. KVO, on the other hand, is designed to register to observe changes to some dynamic property of some other class.

Comment: What is the purpose of `myContext` and how do you observe multiple properties?

Comment: According to [KVO Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html): "When you register an object as an observer, you can also provide a `context` pointer. The `context` pointer is provided to the observer when `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is invoked. The `context` pointer can be a C pointer or an object reference. The `context` pointer can be used as a unique identifier to determine the change that is being observed, or to provide some other data to the observer."

Comment: you need to remove observer in deinit

Comment: @Jacky Agreed. That's where I generally remove the observer. I had simply quoted the Apple documentation, which didn't cover this key point, but it looks like they've finally updated it to reflect this. So I've updated my quote from their documentation accordingly.

Comment: @devth, as I understand, if subclass or superclass also registers KVO observer for the same variable, observeValueForKeyPath will be called multiple times. Context can be used to distinguish own notifications in this situation. More on this: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/09/24/proper_kvo_usage/

Comment: need to change: [NSObject : AnyObject]? to [String : AnyObject]?

Comment: @LeoDabus - Agreed. The API has changed. Answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: If I mark it as private it can't be accessed in MyObserver class

Comment: @LeoDabus - If this private global is defined within the same `.swift` file as the `MyObserver` class, it can be accessed fine. And it seems better to do that and keep it `private`, to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Can we KVO the alpha of a view?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/41351175/294884

Comment: I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nskeyvalueobservingoptions) about the options, but still don't get what exactly do they mean in laymen's term. What would happen if you leave the options empty? What would happen if you remove `.old`?

Comment: If you leave `options` empty, it just means that the `change` won't include the old or new value (e.g. you might just get the new value yourself by referencing the object itself). If you just specify `.new` and not `.old`, it means that `change` will include only the new value, but not the old value (e.g. you often don't care about what the old value was, but only care about the new value). If you need `observeValueForKeyPath` to pass you both the old and new value, then specify `[.new, .old]`. Bottom line, `options` just specifies what is included in the `change` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks...and If I state `prior` then I will get 2 notifications? one for `.old` and another for `.new`? rather than getting a dictionary with 2 different keys? and if I state `initial` ummm not sure really what happens!?

Comment: Re `.prior`, yep, that's it. And re `.initial`, generally when you set up notification, you don't receive a notification _until the value changes._ But you can use `.initial` if you also want to receive a notification when you first set it up (e.g. if the initialization routine is identical to your change routine that you're already doing in `observeValue`, you can use `.initial` to have it called immediately, too). It just depends upon what you're doing in your `observeValue` routine.

Comment: added +1 for nice answer

Answer (score 92):

Both yes and no:

- **Yes**, you can use the same old KVO APIs in Swift to observe Objective-C objects.
  You can also observe `dynamic` properties of Swift objects inheriting from `NSObject`.
  But... **No** it's not strongly typed as you could expect Swift native observation system to be.
  [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C | Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8)
- **No**, currently there is no builtin value observation system for arbitrary Swift objects.
- **Yes**, there are builtin *Property Observers*, which are strongly typed.
  But... **No** they are not KVO, since they allow only for observing of objects own properties, don't support nested observations ("key paths"), and you have to explicitly implement them.
  [The Swift Programming Language | Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_378)
- **Yes**, you can implement explicit value observing, which will be strongly typed, and allow for adding multiple handlers from other objects, and even support nesting / "key paths".
  But... **No** it will not be KVO since it will only work for properties which you implement as observable.
  You can find a library for implementing such value observing here:
  [Observable-Swift - KVO for Swift - Value Observing and Events](https://github.com/slazyk/Observable-Swift)

Answer (score 10):

An example might help a little here.  If I have an instance `model` of class `Model` with attributes `name` and `state` I can observe those attributes with:

```
let options = NSKeyValueObservingOptions([.New, .Old, .Initial, .Prior])

model.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "name", options: options, context: nil)
model.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state", options: options, context: nil)
```

Changes to these properties will trigger a call to:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!,
    ofObject object: AnyObject!,
    change: NSDictionary!,
    context: CMutableVoidPointer) {

        println("CHANGE OBSERVED: \(change)")
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the observeValueForKeyPath call approach is for Swift2.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

KVO requires dynamic dispatch, so you simply need to add the `dynamic` modifier to a method, property, subscript, or initializer:

`dynamic var foo = 0`

The `dynamic` modifier ensures that references to the declaration will be dynamically dispatched and accessed through `objc_msgSend`.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Rob's answer. That class must inherit from `NSObject`, and we have 3 ways to trigger property change

Use `setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String)` from `NSKeyValueCoding`

```
class MyObjectToObserve: NSObject {
    var myDate = NSDate()
    func updateDate() {
        setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "myDate")
    }
}
```

Use `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` from `NSKeyValueObserving`

```
class MyObjectToObserve: NSObject {
    var myDate = NSDate()
    func updateDate() {
        willChangeValueForKey("myDate")
        myDate = NSDate()
        didChangeValueForKey("myDate")
    }
}
```

Use `dynamic`. See [Swift Type Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID57)

> You can also use the dynamic modifier to require that access to members be dynamically dispatched through the Objective-C runtime if you’re using APIs like key–value observing that dynamically replace the implementation of a method.

```
class MyObjectToObserve: NSObject {
    dynamic var myDate = NSDate()
    func updateDate() {
        myDate = NSDate()
    }
}
```

And property getter and setter is called when used. You can verify when working with KVO. This is an example of computed property

```
class MyObjectToObserve: NSObject {
    var backing: NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var myDate: NSDate {
        set {
            print("setter is called")
            backing = newValue
        }
        get {
            print("getter is called")
            return backing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently Swift does not support any built in mechanism for observing property changes of objects other than 'self', so no, it does not support KVO.

However, KVO is such a fundamental part of Objective-C and Cocoa that it seems quite likely that it will be added in the future. The current documentation seems to imply this:

> **Key-Value Observing**
>
> Information forthcoming.

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_5)

Comment: Obviously, that guide you reference now describes how to do KVO in Swift.

Comment: Yep, now implemented as of September 2014

Answer (score 4):

One important thing to mention is that after updating your **Xcode** to **7 beta** you might be getting the following message:
**"Method does not override any method from its superclass"**. That's because of the arguments' optionality. Make sure that your observation handler looks exactly as follows:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
```

Comment: In Xcode beta 6 it requires: override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)

Answer (score 4):

This may be prove helpful to few people -

```
// MARK: - KVO

var observedPaths: [String] = []

func observeKVO(keyPath: String) {
    observedPaths.append(keyPath)
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
}

func unObserveKVO(keyPath: String) {
    if let index = observedPaths.index(of: keyPath) {
        observedPaths.remove(at: index)
    }
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath)
}

func unObserveAllKVO() {
    for keyPath in observedPaths {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath)
    }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let keyPath = keyPath {
        switch keyPath {
        case #keyPath(camera.iso):
            slider.value = camera.iso
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I had used KVO in this way in Swift 3. You can use this code with few changes.

Answer (score 4):

## Overview

It is possible using **`Combine`** without using `NSObject` or `Objective-C`

**Availability:** `iOS 13.0+`, `macOS 10.15+`, `tvOS 13.0+`, `watchOS 6.0+`, `Mac Catalyst 13.0+`, `Xcode 11.0+`

**Note:** Needs to be used only with classes not with value types.

## Code:

**Swift Version: 5.1.2**

```
import Combine //Combine Framework

//Needs to be a class doesn't work with struct and other value types
class Car {

    @Published var price : Int = 10
}

let car = Car()

//Option 1: Automatically Subscribes to the publisher

let cancellable1 = car.$price.sink {
    print("Option 1: value changed to \($0)")
}

//Option 2: Manually Subscribe to the publisher
//Using this option multiple subscribers can subscribe to the same publisher

let publisher = car.$price

let subscriber2 : Subscribers.Sink<Int, Never>

subscriber2 = Subscribers.Sink(receiveCompletion: { print("completion \($0)")}) {
    print("Option 2: value changed to \($0)")
}

publisher.subscribe(subscriber2)

//Assign a new value

car.price = 20
```

## Output:

```
Option 1: value changed to 10
Option 2: value changed to 10
Option 1: value changed to 20
Option 2: value changed to 20
```

## Refer:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving_and_handling_events_with_combine
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published

Comment: iOS 13 +? Other people were just ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Another example for anyone who runs into a problem with types such as Int? and CGFloat?. You simply set you class as a subclass of NSObject and declare your variables as follows e.g:

```
class Theme : NSObject{

   dynamic var min_images : Int = 0
   dynamic var moreTextSize : CGFloat = 0.0

   func myMethod(){
       self.setValue(value, forKey: "\(min_images)")
   }

}
```