# Swift: which class owns the .New property used in NSObject.addObserver( ... options: .New )?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, nsobject, throw, addobserver

The current best practice for KVO in Swift is well documented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092285/is-key-value-observation-kvo-available-in-swift), and would look something like this:

```
someObject.addObserver( self, forKeyPath: "someProperty", options: .New, 
    context: &self.someContext )
```

I want to simplify memory management problems by encapsulating this in an **ObserversManager** (say) class, so I can do things like this:

```
func observe ( observed: NSObject, observer: NSObject, keyPath: String, 
    context: Int )
{
    observed.addObserver( observer, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: .New, 
        context: context ) { ... }
}

func removeObserversByObserver ( observer: NSObject ) { ... }
func removeAllObservers () { ... }
```

The problem is that the above **func observer** throws the following compile time error, which i am at present powerless to fix, as the official documentation does not detail the answer afaict.
`Could not find member 'New'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The problem is that the `context:` parameter is a *pointer*, not an Int:

```
func observe ( observed: NSObject, observer: NSObject, keyPath: String,
    context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> )
{
    observed.addObserver(observer, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: .New,
                         context: context)
}
```