# Observe another class property

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

I have a singleton class that manages location in my app:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        didSet {
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class var manager: Location {
        return UserLocation
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    override init () {
        super.init()

        if self.locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 50


    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if self.currentLocation == nil {
            print("User Location NOT Updated.")
        } else {
            print("did update location")
        }
        self.currentLocation = manager.location!.coordinate

    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    func startLocationUpdate() {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    func stopLocationUpdate() {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

// Mark: - Singleton Location
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let UserLocation = Location()
```

So from anyother class I'm able to call:

```
    let theCurrentLocation = UserLocation.currentLocation
```

**But is it possible to add some observer to this property in another class?**

or

**Is it possible to notify another class, that the property has changed, in some other clever way?**

I found the `addObserver` method, `addObserver(observer: NSObject, forKeyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)` but wasn't sure this could be used in this context. I'm looking for something like this?

```
class AnotherCLass: NSObject {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        // seudo ->
        UserLocation.addObserver(self, UserLocation.currentLocation, "someAction:")
    }

    func someAction() {
        print("currect location has changed..")
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

So I took a look at [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), and it sounds just like what I need. I followed the guide, but I dont get any notification when the property I want to observe is changed. So I add the observer like this:

```
UserLocation.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentLocation", options: .New, context: nil)
```

And the observing method like this:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    print("notification received")
    if keyPath == "currentLocation" {
        print("Current Location received")   
    }
}
```

**But this method is never called, eventhough the ´currentLocation´ is changed...**

Comment: Check this out: [Is key-value observation (KVO) available in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092285/is-key-value-observation-kvo-available-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks, I did check it out, and tried to implement it, but it didn't work for me.. See the edit section..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `var currentLocation` to `dynamic var currentLocation`. You must add the dynamic modifier to any property you want to observe in KVO.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, although it wasn't possible to make an optional dynamic variable.