# Using switch in observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: swift, switch-statement, key-value-observing

I'm attempting to increase legibility of my KVO observeValueForKeyPath implementation by replacing the typical long string of nested if/else statements with a single switch statement.

So far, the only thing that's actually worked is:

```
private let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

    switch (object!, keyPath!) {

    case let (object, "delegate") where object as? UIApplication === application:
        appDelegate = application.delegate
        break

    ...

    default:
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
```

Which, if anything, is even harder to read than:

```
    if object as? UIApplication === application && keyPath! == "delegate" {

    }
    else {

    }
```

Does anybody have a good model for using switch in `observeValueForKeyPath` (and similar methods)

EDIT: Relevant to @critik's question below, here's more of the code to demonstrate the problems with just using `switch (object as! NSObject, keyPath!) {`:

```
private let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
private var appDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate?
private var rootWindow : UIWindow?

public override func observeValueForKeyPath(
    keyPath: String?,
    ofObject object: AnyObject?,
    change: [String : AnyObject]?,
    context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    switch (object as! NSObject, keyPath!) {
    case (application, "delegate"):
        appDelegate = application.delegate
        (appDelegate as? NSObject)?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "window", options: [.Initial], context: nil)
        break

    case (appDelegate, "window"):
        rootWindow = appDelegate?.window?.flatMap { $0 }
        break

    case (rootWindow, "rootViewController"):
        rebuildViewControllerList(rootWindow?.rootViewController)
        break

    default:
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: All you're really saying is that the whole KVO architecture sucks. That's true but it's not new news. We've been up and down this road many, many times. There are many obvious workarounds but in the end it's hard to avoid a huge bottleneck, where everything passes thru this one method, and a massive switch is the standard way of dealing with it.

Comment: @matt more annoying to me right now is how incompletely implemented, or perhaps incompletely used) it is on iOS.  There are many properties on system objects which can't be usefully observed, `UIViewController.presentedViewController` for instance.

Comment: Be thankful. Do you know how KVO works? It reaches right into your object and swizzles it, substituting another object for your object! It's the Work Of The Devil. The fact that we sometimes _have_ to use it is in fact the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using KVO since pretty much the dawn of time.  Conceptually it's a very powerful mechanism, particularly so on MacOS, where you can bind views directly to properties.  I've often lamented the ability to do that on iOS, to the extent that I've hacked together solutions that let me do that on at least a couple of occasions :)

Comment: "where you can bind views directly to properties" Sure, I know. I have applications that rely heavily on this. But of course I can't figure out how they work. :)

Comment: That and removing a non existent observer being a fatal error...

Comment: And forgetting to remove observers in time... :)

Comment: Yep, I want to scream "You're obviously checking for this, JUST FIX IT"

Answer (score 0):

How about a `switch` on tuples:

```
switch (object as! NSObject, keyPath!) {

case (application, "delegate"):
    appDelegate = application.delegate

...

default:
    super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
}
```

**Note 1.** Although I'm agains forced stuff in Swift (downcasts, unwraps, etc), you can safely force downcast to `NSObject` without getting a crash, as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092285/is-key-value-observation-kvo-available-in-swift), KVO is only available for `NSObject` subclasses.

**Note 2.** You also don't need a `break` in Swift, this will also shorten your code by at least one line :)

Comment: I tried a bunch of casting variants, but didn't try NSObject.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work if some of the targets are optional. "Expression pattern of type 'UIApplicationDelegate?' cannot match values of type 'NSObject'"

Comment: @DavidBerry can you post the code that fails? Perhaps I'll find a solution for it :)

Comment: Think I updated it with enough of the code to see the problems.

Comment: @DavidBerry I updated my answer with a solution for the second `switch`

Comment: This code compiles, but it doesn't do the same thing.  Rather than checking to see if `object == application`, your code checks to see if `object is UIApplication` and then assigns it to a new variable named application, ie., it only does a type check.  To see what I mean, change it to `case let (app as UIApplication, "delegate"):` and see that it still compiles.

Comment: Hmm... you might be right, I did test only with one value, and this is why it worked for me. Will get back to you if I find a valid implementation.

Comment: Don't worry about it over much unless you just like to solve problems :).  I've taken a different approach which eliminates this chunk of code completely.

Comment: I kinda like solving problems :). I reverted my answer meanwhile, to not lead other people into error.

Comment: BTW, is your solution `switch` based of `if` based, or did you give up to `observeValueForKeyPath`?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really solve the problem of using `switch` in `observeValueForKey` but it does demonstrate how I simplified the problem space to eliminate the verbose code.

I created a utility class, `KVOValueWatcher` which allows me to add (and remove) KVO observation on a single property of an object:

```
public class KVOValueWatcher<ObjectType:NSObject, ValueType:NSObject> : NSObject {
    public typealias OnValueChanged = (ValueType?, [String:AnyObject]?) -> ()

    let object : ObjectType
    let keyPath : String
    let options : NSKeyValueObservingOptions
    let onValueChanged : OnValueChanged
    var engaged = false

    public init(object:ObjectType, keyPath:String, options : NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [], onValueChanged: OnValueChanged) {
        self.object = object
        self.keyPath = keyPath
        self.onValueChanged = onValueChanged
        self.options = options

        super.init()

        engage()
    }

    deinit {
        if(engaged) {
            print("KVOValueWatcher deleted without being disengaged")
            print("    object: \(object)")
            print("    keyPath: \(keyPath)")
        }

        disengage()
    }

    public func engage() {
        if !engaged {
            self.object.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: options, context: nil)
            engaged = true
        }
    }

    public func disengage() {
        if engaged {
            self.object.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: keyPath)
            engaged = false
        }
    }

    override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        self.onValueChanged(((object as? NSObject)?.valueForKeyPath(keyPath!) as? ValueType), change)
    }
}
```

My problem code then becomes:

```
    rootWindowWatcher = KVOValueWatcher(object: applicationDelegate as! NSObject, keyPath: "window", options: [.Initial]) { window, changes in
        self.rootViewWatcher?.disengage()
        self.rootViewWatcher = nil

        if let window = window {
            self.rootViewWatcher = KVOValueWatcher(object: window, keyPath: "rootViewController", options: [.Initial]) {
                [unowned self] rootViewController, changes in
                self.rootViewController = rootViewController
                self.rebuildActiveChildWatchers()
            }
        }
    }
```

The primary reason for the change was because it was becoming a nightmare to maintain all the different observations and get them properly added and removed.  Adding the wrapper class eliminates the problem and groups watching a property and the action to be taken when the property changes in the same location.