# Getting runtime issue in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime-error

When I am using this line of code:

```
if (context == &KVOContext && keyPath == contentOffsetKeyPath && object as? UIScrollView == scrollView) {
    //...
}
```

I am getting runtime issue which is:

> Simultaneous accesses to 0x7f7eea603fb8, but modification requires
>   exclusive access

I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone give me solution for this?

Comment: Possibly Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x1c0a7f0f8-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access

Comment: No it's different code.

Comment: It doesn't has to be the exact same code, probably you might want to review the answers...

Comment: No it doesn't my issue it get issue at context and i don't know how to solve so i ask here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneous accesses to 0x10f10df48, but modification requires exclusive access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422948/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x10f10df48-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simultaneous accesses to 0x1c0a7f0f8, but modification requires exclusive access error on Xcode 9 beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x1c0a7f0f8-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access)