# Simultaneous accesses to 0x6040000155d8, but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x1c0a7f0f8-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access) SO question and came to know this happens due to read and write at the same time. But in my case I am not able to figure out where I am reading and writing to my array at the same time.

What I am doing is I am removing a subrange from an array before inserting to it. e.g:

```
var createGameOptions = [GOCreateGameDetailsModel]()
for attribute in model.gameAttributes! {
     let model = GOCreateGameDetailsModel.init(title: attribute.attribute_name!, image: nil, value: "", imageUrl: attribute.attribute_icon)
     createGameOptions.append(model)
}
if (createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.count)! > 3 {
    createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.removeSubrange(2...((createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.count)! - 2))
}
createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.insert(contentsOf: createGameOptions, at: 2)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try updating this line

```
createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.removeSubrange(2...((createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.count)! - 2))
```

To

```
let count = (createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.count)!
createGameModel?.createGameOptions?.removeSubrange(2...(count - 2))
```

Try and share the results

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it where the problem is.

Comment: Best answer! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

in Swift 4.2 warnings related to exclusive access become errors, This means project with these warnings will never compile on Swift 4.2

Warnings comes when a mutating method that modifies a variable is passed a non-escaping closure that reads from the same variable. For example:

```
var result = Data(count:prf.cc.digestLength)
let count = result.count
let status = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
            // can not use directly result.count inside this non escaping closure. must computed before using count
}
```

For more detail about this please check this article.
[exclusive access erros](https://forums.swift.org/t/upgrading-exclusive-access-warning-to-be-an-error-in-swift-4-2/12704)