# Swift : Simultaneous accesses to 0x10959c600, but modification requires exclusive access on Structs

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, observers

I want to understand **why** using a struct is causing this issue and a class does not. I encountered the issue when appending elements to array and having an observer load a table. Here are the codes:

Order.swift - items ordered

```
struct Order {
    var menuItems: [MenuItem]
    init(menuItems: [MenuItem] = []) {
        self.menuItems = menuItems
    }
}
```

MenuController.swift - contains the order and a shared instance

```
struct MenuController {  
    static var shared: MenuController = MenuController()
    static let orderNotification = Notification.Name("MenuController.orderUpdated")

    var order = Order() {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MenuController.orderNotification,
                                            object: nil)
    }
}
```

MenuItemViewController.swift - ordering screen

```
@IBAction func orderButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     MenuController.shared.order.menuItems.append(menuItem)
 }
```

OrderTableViewController.swift - items ordered screen

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(tableView, 
                      selector: #selector(UITableView.reloadData),
                      name: MenuController.orderNotification, object: nil)
}
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return MenuController.shared.order.menuItems.count //Simultaneous access error thrown here
}
```

Now, I made a design mistake where MenuController should be a **class** instead of a struct because we're gonna be sharing MenuController instance throughout the app hence it should be a reference type. Using a class solved the simultaneous access issue.

What I am confused about is : 
*Why is a value-typed (struct) MenuController causing this simultaneous access issue when observer try to load the tableView.*

Hope someone can explain. TIA!

Answer (score 6):

It has to do with 'Exclusive Access to Memory' and is explaind well here:
[Simultaneous accesses to 0x1c0a7f0f8, but modification requires exclusive access error on Xcode 9 beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/simultaneous-accesses-to-0x1c0a7f0f8-but-modification-requires-exclusive-access)

The short version: A var cannot be 'readable' and 'writeable' at the same time. When a `set` action starts, the var is 'writeable', if a `get` action occur ('readable') while the var is still 'writeable', it will trigger an exception.

On `didSet`, var is 'writeable'. If actions in `didSet` leads somewhere in the call stack to the var being read, it will trigger the exception.

Even without a `didSet`, if you have a mutating function that sets a var and then post a notification, where the observer of the notification will attempt to read it, same exception will be triggered.

Comment: Does this apply only to structs, or to classes as well?

Comment: @Drew I think this is both classes and struct, it's related more to the var access, not the enclosing context.

Answer (score 0):

My case was different than @bauerMusic 's answer.

I put my related code in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block (main thread) & it is solved.

So was a thread issue for my case.