# How to search for users

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to search for my users that are saved in firebase but when I click on the user, my app crash and I receive this error

> Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x6000031ad8d0, but modification requires exclusive access

What does this error mean and how do I fix this code to remove this error ?

```
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @StateObject var viewModel = SearchViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView{
                LazyVStack(spacing: 12){
                    ForEach(viewModel.users ) { user in
                        NavigationLink(value: user) {
                            HStack{
                                Image("Logo")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(user.username)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 8)
                    .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Search...")
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { user in
                    ProfileView(user: user)
                    })
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415901/ ?

Comment: no it still giving me the same error @koen

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code where you get the crash as a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: I took the full code off @koen

Comment: That’s not an [example].

Comment: it doesn't get any minimal than that and that's the exact line giving me problem so I just reposted the full code @koen

Comment: Minimal: yes. Reproducible: No.

Comment: is the code I have now reproducible @koen