# SceneKit SCNPhysicsBody get notified of resting

Tags: scenekit, physics-engine

`SceneKit`
Is there a way to get notified when `dynamicBody` is in resting State ?
I want to remove `dynamicBody` when it finished to fall to the ground and stopped moving completely - I presume that I will have quite large amount of those so I would like to use something event based rather than looping through all the `bodies` and checking their velocities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Key-Value Observation on the `isResting` property. See [Is key-value observation (KVO) available in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092285/is-key-value-observation-kvo-available-in-swift).

Or you could use the `SCNPhysicsContact` and `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate` to detect collisions with the floor, and use that to trigger a check for velocity.

Comment: It has some cost. You could measure it to find out how much, exactly. More at issue is that KVO isn't very Swift-y (you didn't mention the language you're using). I don't remember offhand what the sequence is of the SCNPhysicsContact callback, the renderer(_:didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:) callback from the SCNSceneRenderer, and the update of the objects' speeds; you might have to enqueue the node for deletion in one callback and delete it in another. Using the contact delegate feels like better Swift style to me, although I can't articulate precisely why.

Comment: I am using - Objective-C, I asked on performance because I am tight on CPU - animations takes almost 13ms + flush and stuff... I have left less than 1.2 ms - honestly Pathetic...

Comment: It's not much work to implement each approach and then measure/compare. Premature optimization being the root of all evil, according to some famous person :-)

Comment: I stuck in the mid way to there, will have to handle it first then will try both as you suggest.

Guess I better gonna post a question about Animation optimisations.