# How to add an observer for some properties of SCNPhysicsBody?

Tags: swift, observable, scenekit, observers

I am trying to get notified when the body stops rolling over.

After [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309204/scenekit-scnphysicsbody-get-notified-of-resting) post was trying to add some observers for SCNPhysicsBody. However, since I am new to iOS development, did smth wrong and don't know how to add an observer for this kind of properties.

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```swift
body.physicsBody!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(SCNPhysicsBody.isResting), options: [.new, .old], context: nil)
```

And func

```swift
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {     
    print("resting")
}
```

Also tried to put only this line in `viewDidLoad()`:

```swift
body.physicsBody!.observe(\.isResting, changeHandler: { (_, _) in
    print("resting")
})
```

Nothing printed

Comment: I still don't know how to add an observer for the properties of the framework, so this is just a comment. To get notified of body rest, I added protocol SCNSceneRendererDelegate and func renderer(_:,didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:) where I checked whether the body is resting.