# Swift 4 approach for observeValue(forKeyPath:...)

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value-observing, keypaths

I've been trying to find an example, but what I've seen doesn't work in my case.

What would be the equivalent of the following code:

```
object.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "keyPath", options: [.new], context: nil)

override public func observeValue(
    forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
    of object: Any?, 
    change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, 
    context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

}
```

The code above works, but I get a warning from SwiftLink:

> Prefer the new block based KVO API with keypaths when using Swift 3.2 or later.

I appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1714) can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is key-value observation (KVO) available in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092285/is-key-value-observation-kvo-available-in-swift)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Swift 4 introduced a family of concrete [Key-Path types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/key_path_expressions), a new [Key-Path Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/wildcard-expression) to produce them and a new closure-based [observe](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L185) function available to classes that inherit `NSObject`.

Using this new set of features, your particular example can now be expressed much more succinctly:

```
self.observation = object.observe(\.keyPath) { 
    [unowned self] object, change in
    self.someFunction()
}
```

**Types Involved**

- `observation:`[`NSKeyValueObservation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyvalueobservation)
- `change:`[`NSKeyValueObservedChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyvalueobservedchange)
- `\.keyPath`: An instance of a [KeyPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath) class produced at compile time.

**Key-Path grammar**

The general [grammar](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/key-path-expression) of a Key-Path Expression follows the form `\Type.keyPath` where `Type` is a concrete type name (incl. any generic parameters), and `keyPath` a chain of one or more properties, subscripts, or optional chaining/forced unwrapping postfixes. In addition, if the keyPath's Type can be inferred from context, it can be elided, resulting in a most pithy `\.keyPath`.

These are all valid Key-Path Expressions:

```
\SomeStruct.someValue
\.someClassProperty
\.someInstance.someInnerProperty
\[Int].[1]
\[String].first?.count
\[SomeHashable: [Int]].["aStringLiteral, literally"]!.count.bitWidth
```

**Ownership**

You're the owner of the `NSKeyValueObservation` instance the `observe` function returns, meaning, *you don't have to* `addObserver` nor `removeObserver` anymore; rather, you keep a strong reference to it for as long as you need your observation observing.

You're *not* required to `invalidate()` either: it'll `deinit` gracefully. So, you can let it live until the instance holding it dies, stop it manually by `nil`ing the reference, or even invoke `invalidate()` if you need to keep your instance alive for some smelly reason.

**Caveats**

As you may have noticed, observation still lurks inside the confines of Cocoa's KVO mechanism, therefore it's only available to Obj-C classes and Swift classes inheriting `NSObject` (every Swift-dev's favorite type) with the added requirement that any value you intend to observe, must be marked as `@objc` (every Swift-dev's favorite attribute) and declared `dynamic`.

That being said, the overall mechanism is a welcomed improvement, particularly because it manages to Swiftify observing imported `NSObjects` from modules we may happen to be required to use (eg. `Foundation`), and without risking weakening the expressive power we work so hard to obtain with every keystroke.

As a side-note, [Key-Path **String** Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/selector-expression) are still required to [dynamically access](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective_c_runtime_features_in_swift) `NSObject`'s properties to KVC or call `value(forKey(Path):)`

**Beyond KVO**

There's much more to Key-Path Expressions than KVO. `\Type.path` expressions can be stored as `KeyPath` objects for later reuse. They come in writable, partial and type-erased flavors. They can augment the expressive power of getter/setter functions designed for composition, not to mention the role they play in allowing those with the strongest of stomachs to delve into the world of functional concepts like Lenses and Prisms. I suggest you check the links down below to learn more about the many development doors they can open.

**Links:**

[Key-Path Expression @ docs.swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#//appleref/swift/grammar/wildcard-expression)

[KVO docs @ Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key_value_observing_in_swift)

[Swift Evolution Smart KeyPaths proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md)

[Ole Begemann's Whats-new-in-Swift-4 playground with Key-Path examples](https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4/blob/master/Whats-new-in-Swift-4.playground/Pages/Key%20paths.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift)

[WWDC 2017 Video: What's New in Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/) *4:35 for SKP and 19:40 for KVO.*

Comment: can you point me to where to find what you said on your "Ownership" section? I'm looking for it on the reference but I don't see it.

Comment: @dava As far as I know, the closest you'll get to an official, explicit mention in text are the docstrings for [invalidate](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L160) and [observe](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L185). Both will show on Xcode's quickhelp as expected. I've also added a WWDC video with this and expanded the ownership section.

Answer (score 10):

To add something to the answer as I experienced crashes on my app when using this method in iOS 10.

In iOS 10, you still need to remove the observer before deallocating the class or otherwise you will get a crash `NSInternalInconsistencyException` stating that:

> An instance `A` of Class `C` was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

To avoid this crash. Simply set the observer property that you're using to `nil`.

```
deinit {
    self.observation = nil
}
```

Comment: It's the same issue with Notifications. If you use the block based methods you need to explicitly set the returned value to nil in deinit. The non-block based observers don't need to do this.

Comment: Great addendum! Just to be super clear, this issue is _not_ observed on newer iOSes, right?

Comment: iOS 11 handles this automatically. I will assume iOS 12 as well but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @barbarity do you have a source for that?

Comment: For what specifically?