# Subclassing NSObject for a singleton performing networking tasks?

Tags: ios, swift3, singleton, nsurlsession, nsobject

I'm checking an example of the use of `URLSession` and the networking tasks are performed by a singleton class that is more or less like this:

```
class NetworkManager: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()
fileprivate var session: URLSession
fileprivate var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

override init() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    super.init()
}

func search(searchUrl: URL, completion: @escaping NetResult) {
    dataTask?.cancel()

    dataTask = session.dataTask(with: searchUrl, completionHandler: completion)

    dataTask?.resume()
}

// Some other methods

}
```

This class also conforms to `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` in an `extension`.

What is the benefit of subclassing `NSObject` here?

Comment: you must have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057525/swift-native-base-class-or-nsobject/

Comment: @AmrElAdawy thanks, but that post looks like providing quite generic guidelines for me. What about my particular case, that is, a singleton that performs networking?

Comment: I think I am not fully getting your question, but I had a look on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943371/swift-3-subclassing-nsobject-or-not   It has some good explanation about extending NSObject or not.