# Polymorphism by method parameters split across base and inherited classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class General {
    public:
        General() {};

        void print(void) {
            cout << "From General\n";
        }
};

class Special : public General {
    public:
        Special() {};

        void print(int c) {
            cout << "From Special\n";
        }
};

int main() {
    Special s;
    s.print(3);  // want to print from Special
    s.print();  // want to print from General
}
```

The output that I would like to see is:

```
From Special
From General
```

However, I get this compilation error (referring to the very last `print()` call):

```
error #165: too few arguments in function call
```

I want the compiler to recognize which `print` method to call based on the number and types of arguments I provide. If these 2 methods were defined within the same class, then it would work perfectly. But here, they are split across the base and derived classes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Add `using General::print;` in `Special`.

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451516/overloading-a-base-class-function-in-the-derived-class

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by adding a **using declaration** inside `Special` as shown below. This works because a using declaration for a base-class member function(like `print` in your case) adds all the overloaded instances of that function to the scope of the derived class.

```
class Special : public General {
    public:
        Special() {};
//------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->added this using declaration
        using General::print;
        void print(int c) {
            cout << "From Special\n";
        }
        
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/KBeHC7K6g)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
int main() {
    Special s;
    s.print(3);  // want to print from Special
    s.General::print();  // want to print from General
}
```