# c++ double pointer polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I'm trying to create an array of pointers using polymorphism. I will have the array of the superclass point to multiple subclasses. Is there anyway of doing this and still using a method from the subclass? Here's a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>


class Test1
{
public:
    Test1()
        : x(1)
    {}
    int get_x()
    {
        return x;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

class Test2 : public Test1
{
public:
    Test2()
        : y(2)
    {}
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << get_x() << ' ' << y << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int y;
};

class Test3 : public Test1
{
public:
    Test3()
        : y(3)
    {}
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << get_x() << ' ' << y << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Test1** test = new Test1*[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            test[i] = NULL;
            test[i] = new Test2;
        }
        else
        {
            test[i] = NULL;
            test[i] = new Test3;
        }
    }

    test[0]->print(); // ERROR. Is this even possible?
    test[1]->print(); // ERROR. Is this even possible?


    return 0;
}
```

Thank you I've only been coding for about 8 months.

Comment: You'll want to read up on [virtual functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> test[0]->print(); // ERROR. Is this even possible?

In general, yes. However, not with your code.

1. If `Test1` is going to be your base class and you're going to use `new` then it **must** have a virtual destructor (e.g., `virtual ~Test1() {}`)

   - This is necessary for `delete` to work correctly when deleting a derived type via a pointer to the base class
2. Any function you want to call using a pointer to the base class must exist on the base class (i.e., you need a `print` function in `Test1`)
3. If you want the derived classes to have their own implementation of `print` then it must be declared `virtual` in the base class (e.g., `virtual void print();`)

   - If it dosn't make sense for `Test1` to have an implementation of the `print` function then it can declare it *pure virtual* and not provide an implementation (e.g., `virtual void print() = 0;`) thus making it an *abstract* class

Comment: Can you be more specific on the virtual descructor? is my code in the superclass just virtual ~Test1(){} and in the sub classes I create destructors as well?

Comment: See [When to use virtual destructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

Comment: Ok so I guess I don't totally understand this. Will a virtual descructor work in my case? Because won't a virtual descructor make the class virtual and therefor I could never do this: Test1** test = new Test1*[2];. (I read the link you provided by don't really understand how it's supposed to work)

Comment: @aglasscage **No**, you will still be able to instantiate `Test1` with a virtual destructor and **you must have one** because you need to call `delete` on the base pointer (which is for derived types). You cannot instantiate an _abstract_ class (i.e., you wouldn't want to do #3).

Comment: I added the destructor and got it working. Thanks a lot man I appreciate all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

It would be if `Test1` had such a member function named `print`. Your code doesn't compile as-is because `Test::print` doesn't exist. So at the very least, you will have to define that member function. For it to be truly polymorphic, as the intent of the question suggests, you should make `Test::print` a `virtual` member function so that `Test2`'s and `Test3`'s implementations of that function would get called instead:

```
class Test1 { 
    ...
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "Test1" << std::endl;
    }
    ...
};
```

For more information, see [this tutorial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) on virtual functions.

Comment: Thanks man. The virtual function did the trick. Much appreciated!