# How can I check which derivate is it of one class and how can I work with their structure in a list

Tags: c++, class, derivative

I have the following problem and I hope the great community can help me.
If I have a class one:

```
class one
{
private:
  int data;

public:
  one();
  void safe();
  void load();
};
```

And then 2 derivative classes of class one:

```
class two: public one
{
private:
  int data2;
public:
  two();
  safe();
  load();
};

class three: public one
{
private:
  int    data3;
  string data4;
public:
  three();
  void safe();
  void load();
};
```

And now I have to store data in these classes. The object of the classes are stored in a List. And one Element of these List can be in this example one object of class two or class three. Now If I have to save the content of a list in a file I need to get data of `data2` or If I have the other object I need `data3` and `data4`.

How can I check which derivate it is and how can I get the data of the objects? I mean that must be possible because they are both derivatives of one.

Comment: I suggest you learn about `virtual` methods.

Comment: You are right. But it is not that easy if your prof try to teach you a language and explain you alot of stuff wrong :/ But I think I found a nice explanation about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-methods-in-c

Comment: Glad I can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list:

```
std::list<one*> myList;
```

if you need a collection like an array

```
std::vector<one*> myVec;
```

You can see more details on how to inesrt and process data from list  `std::list` here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

For `std::vector<>` here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

For your second question:

> How can I check which derivate it is and how can I get the data of the
>   objects?

Since you already created an inheritance and going to keep objects as pointers in container like `std::list` or `std::vector`, system can identify the dynamic type of the objects using polymorphism and invoke the functions depends on the type of the object. More details are available here : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: I have to write my own list and the list is working aswell. My List is a template which can be any object of data storage. The problem I have is that I dont know how to know if there is stored data of a object from class two or from class three. So I can't just say getData() and then I get the right answer.

Comment: @missjohanna  Are you keeping one ,two and three in a single list or do you keep separate class objects in separate list? What is the template type parameter for your list?

Comment: I keep two and three in a single list. The template type parameter of my list are class one, so I can use class two and three for data storage. But I handle my List as a derivate of my Element class which is a template aswell. For example I initiate it with list<one> * list1 = new list<one>; Hope that helps to show my point

Comment: @missjohanna you are facing object slicing , to keep objects properly in container  in your case, you should use list<one*>.

Comment: you are right I should better use a pointer from the class one in a list. Or are you going to say I cant use my own list class? Why I should not use list<one*> * ? Isn't that possible aswell?

Comment: list<one*> *  this you can. So now each of your objects in your container going to keep their type info also, I hope, it will solve your issue.