# How can I implement a vector<class> template's function?

Tags: c++

I want to implement a template like this,

```
class animal{
}
class beast : public animal {
public:
beast(string name){}
void cry(){
cout<<"kuuuuu"<<endl;
}
}
int main(){
vector<animal*> a;
a.push_back(beast("tiger"))
vector[0].cry();
}
```

I want to implement similar to it. But my visualstudio cannot find the cry() function.

Please, how can I do it?

Comment: Please format your code properly and fix all compiler errors unrelated to the question.

Comment: Patently, your `class animal` does not declare a `cry` function...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need Virtual Methods in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-methods-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

`animal` does not have a `cry` method. So you cannot call a `cry` on animal.

Also you have numerous syntax errors, which should give you errors before this line:

Your vector contains pointers and you are trying to stuff object itself inside.

To access member of object pointer points to, you should use `->`, not `.`.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of changes needed.`static_cast` is essential to call your `cry` method.

1. class definition should end with `;`
2. Since you created `vector<animal*>`,  you need to `new` the object before push back.
3. When you invoke the function `cry` , you need to `static_cast` it back to `beast*` and use `->` instead `.` to invoke the cry function.

> ```
> class animal{
>
> };
> class beast : public animal {
> public:
>  beast(std::string name){}
> void cry(){
> std::cout<<"kuuuuu"<<std::endl;
> }
> };
> int main(){
> std::vector<animal*> a;
> a.push_back(new beast("tiger"));
> (static_cast<beast*>(a[0]))->cry();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class animal {
public:
    virtual void cry() = 0; // declare public virtual cry method
};

class beast : public animal {
public:

    beast(string name) {
    }

    void cry() {
        cout << "kuuuuu" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<animal*> a;
    a.push_back(new beast("tiger")); // create new object and end with semicolon
    a[0]->cry(); // use -> instead of . to call cry method of beast object pointed at
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<animal>>` instead of manually managing memory.

Comment: That's a good point. But maybe that would be a bit too much for the OP. I focused on correction and explanation.