# How to resolve not a member of base class when create derived object using new operator

Tags: c++, oop

How to resolve not  a member of base class when create derived object using new operator

When i execute the below program, i am getting the below error only when i create a object using new operator "shape *s=new Rectangle";. But i havent faced any issues when i create object "Rectangle s"

Actually i dont want to use hello method in my Triangle class. Need to acces/uses hello method in rectangle class by creating object using new operator "shape *s=new Rectangle".

Please let us know how to resolve this issue using new operator.

Error:

```
1>c:\shape\shape\shape.cpp(60) : error C2039: 'hello' : is not a member of 'Shape'
1>c:\shape\shape\shape.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'Shape'
```

Code snippet:

```
// Shape.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Shape 
{
public:
   // pure virtual function providing interface framework.
   virtual int getArea() = 0;

   void setWidth(int w)
   {
      width = w;
   }
   void setHeight(int h)
   {
      height = h;
   }
protected:
   int width;
   int height;
};

// Derived classes
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
   int getArea()
   { 
      return (width * height); 
   }
   void hello()
   {
        std:cout<<std::endl<<"hello"<<std::endl;
   }
};
class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
   int getArea()
   { 
      return (width * height)/2; 
   }
};

int main(void)
{

   Shape *s= new Rectangle;
  // Triangle  Tri;

   s->setWidth(5);
   s->setHeight(7);
   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total Rectangle area: " << s->getArea() << endl;
   s->hello();
/*
   Tri.setWidth(5);
   Tri.setHeight(7);
   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total Triangle area: " << Tri.getArea() << endl; 
*/
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is different from your problem.

Comment: ^^ this is right. You're mistaking a inheritance issue with the fact that you've told your pointer that it needs to be a pointer to Shape, not Rectangle. Shape doesn't know about hello(). Virtual void hello() in shape or just make a Rectangle* instead of a Shape* if thats viable.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer to `Shape`, but (and this is what your compiler tells you) `Shape` has no member `hello()`.

So theres two ways to access it:
Either you cast it to `Rectangle*` first (which might fail for non-rectangles) or you create a function `virtual void hello()` in `Shape` which is then resolved at compile-time - for all classes that inherit from Shape.

Comment: Oops, just commented something similar on OP's post but this is dead on the money

Comment: or use dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(s) if you are sure it's a rectangle

Comment: When i do type casting to Rectangle *, it works for me.. Thank you for your answer.  But virtual void hello() in Shape, it doesnt resolve this issue. pls let me know how to resolve using "virtual void hello()"

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-methods-in-c) - the accepted answer provides in good detail how to use virtual functions and why they are useful.