# C++ - unwanted use of base method

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class `A` and a few derived classes `B`, `C` and `D`, that all have a method `DoSomething()`, which is virtual in the base class method (it's implemented in all sub classes as well as in the base class).

I have a problem, that the derived class B uses the method from the base class A. This may be the result of bad design, but I do not see the problem as the implementation is pretty straight forward.

An object of class B that is created in the following

```
A* a = new B();
```

If I call the method `DoSomething()` for this object, the method of the base class is used:

```
a->DoSomething(); //Results in Base class method being called.
```

But I expect/want that the method of class B is used.  Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Do you ask about `virtual`? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-methods-in-c?rq=1?

Comment: You need to post the code.

Comment: Why are you allocating from dynamic memory?  C++ is not Java or C#.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Maybe he needs runtime polymorphism?

Answer (score 4):

According to the symptoms that you describe:

- either you have forgotten the virtual keyword in the base class member definition.
- or you have a subtle difference in you signature in the derived class.

The way forward would be to indicate in the derived class that the function is an override:

```
class A { 
   ...
   virtual void DoSometing(); 
}; 
class D : public A {
   ...
   void DoSomething() override; 
};
```

In this case, in case of mismatch you'll get a clear compiler error message.

Answer (score 0):

The following example implements what you asked for.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    virtual void DoSomething()
    {
            std::cout << "A::DoSomething" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    virtual void DoSomething()
    {
            std::cout << "B::DoSomething" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A *a = new B();
    a->DoSomething();
    delete(a);

    return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
B::DoSomething
```