# Avoiding repeated code with C++ derived classes

Tags: c++

I'm writing two programs, let's say a calculator and a chess game. They share a lot of code (interface management, file opening/saving), and I'm trying to figure out the best practice to avoid repeating code.

My idea was to create a parent class, let's call it Generic_Program, which has all the common functions, and derive child classes.

The problem I run into is how I could call a derived class' function instead of the parent one. Conrete example with saving configuration and exiting:

```
class Generic_Program {
    void SaveConfig() {
        // Write general parameters to a file
    }
    void Exit() {
        SaveConfig(); //First save configuration
        // Configuration saved, do exit routines, like make window invisible, etc.
    }
}

class Calculator : Generic_Program {
    void SaveConfig() {
        Generic_Program::SaveConfig(); //Write generic parameters
        // Write calculator-specific data, like calculation results, etc.
    }
}

class Chess : Generic_Program {
    void SaveConfig() {
        Generic_Program::SaveConfig(); //Write generic parameters
        // Write chess-specific data, like player scores, etc.
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to be able to call `Exit()` from both programs. The desired behaviour is that they both save their generic and specific data, then exit.

If I do it with the above code, it will call the parent class' SaveConfig() and thus will save only generic program data.

I could of course write specific `Exit()` routines for child classes, but the point is to write shared code only once.

Is there a method to call `SaveConfig()` of the children from the parent class? Or a best practice for avoiding repeated code in this case?

Comment: Lookup the template function pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c

Comment: @drescherjm. Nailed it.

Comment: The observer pattern could also do this ....
So many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Thank you all. Will "go back to school" and learn about virtual functions.

Comment: @drescherjm I believe the OP want's to know how to separate common code called in the base class and move out the specific stuff to the derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you would call the child object's exit routine and that exit routine would call the base exit routine.

```
Calculator::exit() {
    GenericProgram::exit(); 
    std::cout << "do Chess configs" << std::endl;
    // if needed can call parent routine again, GenericProgram::finish_configs();   
}
```

If you want to call the Exit routine of the base object and have it call the child object's  Exit. Declare a virtual ExitSub routine in the base object.

```
virtual void GenericProgram::ExitSub();
```

and declare/define a default version in case the base object is called but no child object has been instantiated.

```
Generic_Program::ExitSub() { // do nothing };
```

and declare/define a version for each child object eg:

```
Chess::ExitSub() {
    std::cout << "do chess configs" << std::cout;
}
```

declare/define an Exit routine in the Generic_Program that calls the child objects ExitSub routine.  (this is polymorphism).

```
Generic_Program::Exit() {
    SaveConfig();  // First save configuration
    ExitSub();  // invoke sub object configuration
}
```

then to invoke the exit routine from the base object

```
MyGenericProgram.Exit();
```

Comment: Thank you Gregg. Exactly what I was looking for. The main idea is to avoid repeated Exit() subroutines, and have the parent call their children's SaveConfig(). Your example does exactly that.