# Calling subclass (virtual) function (late binding), when not dealing with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Looking at the answer [Why do we need virtual functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c), they show that virtual functions allow late binding, which results in being able to call subclass functions, when being downcasted.

For completness, I include the code in question.

```
class Animal
{
 public:
   virtual void eat() { 
       std::cout << "I'm eating generic food.";
   }
};
class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
  void eat() { std::cout << "I'm eating a rat."; }
};
```

Now consider the following two function

```
void func(Animal *xyz) { xyz->eat(); }
void func2(Animal xyz) { xyz.eat(); }
```

We see that calling func results in

```
Animal *animal = new Animal;
Cat *cat = new Cat;
func(animal); // outputs: "I'm eating generic food."
func(cat);    // outputs: "I'm eating a rat."
```

While calling func2 results in

```
Animal animal;
Cat cat;
func2(animal); // outputs: "I'm eating generic food."
func2(cat);    // outputs: "I'm eating generic food."
```

My question is:

How can I make it so, that functions receiving arguments, that are not pointers, to instances of subclasses, will use the overriden methods? In other words, how can func2 result in  "I'm eating a rat.". Further, I would like to understand why this difference arises. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make it so, that functions receiving arguments, that are not pointers, to instances of subclasses, will use the overriden methods? In other words, how can func2 result in "I'm eating a rat.".

You can use references instead of pointers.

```
void func2(Animal& xyz) { xyz.eat(); }
```

Then, using

```
Animal animal;
Cat cat;
func2(animal);
func2(cat);
```

will work as you are hoping.

> Further, I would like to understand why this difference arises.

That is caused by object slicing. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) to understand what object slicing is and how that comes into play in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to re-do the code in such a way, so that references are not needed? I am dealing with implementing 2 classes, where the general behavior is needed.

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer, to get the dynamic dispatch, or late binding as you call it, you will need to pass either a pointer or a reference. You cannot get the dynamic dispatch if you pass an object. Read up on object slicing to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The whole virtual function mechanism in C++ is based on the idea of selecting the actual function to call based on the *dynamic* ("actual") type of the object used in that call. In this function

```
void func2(Animal xyz) { xyz.eat(); }
```

the type of `xyz` object is `Animal`. It is explicitly hardcoded to be `Animal`. Its static type is `Animal`. Its dynamic type is `Animal`. It is `Animal` in all respects. You yourself asked the compiler to make it so by using the above parameter declaration.

Which means that `xyz.eat();` call will always call `Animal::eat()`. There's no way around it. There's no way to make it call `Cat::eat()` since there's no `Cat` object involved here. By passing a `Cat` as an actual argument, you are simply asking the compiler to generate an `Animal xyz` from that `Cat` and then ignore the original `Cat`. (This is what is often referred to as "slicing".) All subsequent work is done with `Animal xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is the `func2` function **does not** work with the object you pass to it. The function has its own argument variable `Animal xyx` which is *constructed* from your `animal` or `cat` variable. So inside the `func2` you always have a base-class object to work on, hence the function always invokes the generic answer.

```
void func2(Animal xyz)  // uses its own Animal xyz, created on call
{
    xyz.eat();          // uses a local xyz object of Animal class with its generic functions
}

Cat cat;
func2(cat);       // here a new Animal xyz is created from the cat
```

You must pass either a pointer or a reference to your actual object as a parameter to the function to allow the function access the object's specific overridden virtual functions. Like this:

```
void func2(Animal& xyz)   // uses a reference to the argument object
{
    xyz.eat();            // the actual argument is used with its overridden functions
}

Cat cat;
func2(cat);               // the cat is passed to the callee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your classes using value semantics. Then you don't need pointers or references. See "[Better Code: Runtime Polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg)" by Sean Parent, which may just blow your mind. [Here's the code](https://github.com/sean-parent/sean-parent.github.io/blob/e9a297e7312dd56131852d64128c5d0080cc4bf0/presentations/2016-10-10-runtime-polymorphism/value-semantics-unique.cpp). Watch the talk and see how he uses value semantics to avoid bad data sharing and implement an impressive, polymorphic undo system. Here's an annotated sample:

```
// A generic draw function that any type that streams to std::ostream can use
template <typename T>
void draw(const T& x, ostream& out, size_t position)
{ 
  out << string(position, ' ') << x << endl; 
}

// A class that can hold anything with value semantics
// -- note: no virtual functions and no inheritance!
class object_t {
    // ... see the talk for the details here ...
    // This is where the magic happens
};

// Define a vector of our object_t to be a document
using document_t = vector<object_t>;

// Overload the draw() function for document - just iterate
// through the vector and call draw() on each item in it
void draw(const document_t& x, ostream& out, size_t position)
{
    out << string(position, ' ') << "<document>" << endl;
    for (auto& e : x) draw(e, out, position + 2);
    out << string(position, ' ') << "</document>" << endl;
}

// Define my own class that the code above knows nothing 
// about and that doesn't inherit from object_t
class my_class_t {
    /* ... */
};

// Overload draw for it
void draw(const my_class_t&, ostream& out, size_t position)
{ out << string(position, ' ') << "my_class_t" << endl; }

// Use all this stuff
int main()
{
    document_t document; // just a vector!

    // Add some objects that don't inherit from object_t!
    document.emplace_back(0);
    document.emplace_back(string("Hello!"));

    // Show what we've got so far
    draw(document, cout, 0);

    // Add some more stuff
    document.emplace_back(document); // Add a whole copy of the current doc!
    document.emplace_back(my_class_t()); // Add an arbitrary type that doesn't inherit from object_t!

    draw(document, cout, 0);
}
```

This prints:

```
<document>
  0
  Hello!
</document>
<document>
  0
  Hello!
  <document>
    0
    Hello!
  </document>
  my_class_t
</document>
```

See it run on <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/maaJZpTHwFQJJ2vU)</kbd>.

*Look again -- you just got polymorphic behavior without having to explicitly  inherit from a base class.* (Hint: he uses overloading as the primary mechanism rather than inheritance.)

See also this [blog post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/) describing this approach.