# Is a member function virtual by default?

Tags: c++

I am reading about classes in Python and encountered the following statement:

> In C++ terminology, normally class members (including the data
>   members) are public (except see below Private Variables), **and all
>   member functions are virtual.**

I have never heard this, is it true? I tried doing some research, but I only found articles explaining when to make a function virtual and what virtual means.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c

Comment: I think the quote has itself confused, it is not true, certainly not true that data members are public in a class!

Comment: This is a statement about Python, not about C++. It is of course false when applied to C++.

Comment: @n.m. well, he says "in C++ terminology"?

Comment: Doesn't it mean "if you want to do the same thing in C++ as Python, you need to make all the member function public and virtual." ?

Comment: Yes, it is a statement about Python expressed in C++ terminology. Your Python course doesn't attempt to teach you C++. It teaches you Python. It explains how Python behaves, using vocabulary you might know from C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a statement about python.  It is saying to a person who knows C++, that python classes have public members and virtual functions.

So the statement is true, but slightly out of context.