# Compiler behavior with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a question about the compiler behavior when I use up-casting in C++.
For example I have this simple code:

```
class Animal {

public:
    Animal() {}

    void talk() {
        std::cout << "I am an animal" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dog :public Animal {

public:
    Dog(){}

    void talk() {
        std::cout << "I am a dog" << std::endl;
    }

    void eat() {
        std::cout << "eating" << std::endl;
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    Animal* animal = new Dog();
    animal->talk();//Output is "I am an animal"
    //animal->eat();//Compilation error.
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, where does the compiler go first when I run this? Does it look for the methods in Animal class, and then because I didn't use virtual it calls for the Animal's talk() method, or does it checks if the method exists in the Dog class first, and calls for the Animal's method?

Comment: [What did your book say?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) This really isn't something to appeal to SO about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need Virtual Functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Given your code, `animal->talk()` will always call `Animal::talk()`. Because `animal` is a `Animal *` and `Animal::talk()` is not virtual.

Now if you make `Animal::talk()` virtual, `animal->talk()` will call `Dog::talk()`. Normally this is done by looking at run-time at the vtable of `animal` to see the real type of the object and then call the most appropriate `talk()` function. But since you have `Animal *animal = new Dog()` just above, the compiler can choose to optimize the call by skipping the vtable lookup and make a direct call to `Dog::talk()` as the type is already known at compile time.