# Sean Parent: for polymorphic types in an inheritance hierarchy, having mutable object is the extreme exception

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am wondering what Sean Parent actually means 
[by this statement](https://youtu.be/QGcVXgEVMJg?t=2876)

> for polymorphic types in an inheritance hierarchy, having mutable object is the extreme exception...

he goes on to mention two reasons for this but I am having trouble grasping his explanation.

What prevents me from supplying a function in a subclass that actually changes the internals ob this very object?

can somebody please elaborate on this?

Comment: I'm also studying his talk! Good luck hermano

Comment: Me too +1 for this

Comment: anyone having an explanation?

Comment: **context is important!** After watching the video for a few seconds, I think the statement shouldn't be taken out of context. He seems to be talking about a specific technique or design pattern. Furthermore the description of the video says "how to implement polymorphism without inheritance in C++". So whoever gives an explanation about this should be familiar with his presentation, because it does look like it's an advice for a specific scenario, not a general "don't do this".

Comment: I was wondering exactly the same. I have no idea what he is talking about. And of course, I would love to discuss the design with modifying (non-const) methods.

Comment: well this is what std::any is providing at its core. It facilitates mutability with std::any_casts. So this topic is more or less deprecated with the advent of C++17

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

After studying the video for an hour - I figured out what he means.

At 47:49 he starts saying:

> Do we actually modify this object - and the internals of it? An observation is that for polymorphic use cases of objects - **having mutable objects - is the extreme, extreme exception where there is benefit for that**. And there's a good reason why. So if I have a virtual function that's **mutating** my object - OK? - Then, what I am doing is one of two things. I'm either saying that my sub-classes can provide a different implementation, which that very problematic because that's going to change the performance guarantees of that operation and potentially a bunch of other operations on my object or I'm saying that my subclasses want to observe when this thing is set but they're not actually mutating it so rather than having them override my mutating virtual functions what I should do is provide an observer function where I will call them when I have changed things...

He means it literally.

> ...have a virtual function that's **mutating** my object...

Hence, he is stating that it is seldom that you have an inheritance hirachy like...

```
Animal
+-Cat
+-Dog
| +-Doberman
+-Bird
```

...where you want to change the state (mutate) of different polymorphic variants with on virtual method that has different implementations.

E.g.

```
int main() {

    Animal* apObject[] = { new Cat(), new Dog(), new Doberman() };

    const   int cnAnimals = sizeof(apObject)/sizeof(Animal*);
    for ( int i = 0; i < cnAnimals; i++ ) {
        apObject[i]->Feed(1.3);
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < cnAnimals; i++ ) {
        delete apObject[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All animals get food by application of the polymorphic function ("Feed"), but different implemtations are modifying the state differently.

He says this is extreme, extreme seldom!

### My comment

Sean Parent experienced problems with copying polymorphic objects using copy constructors and assignment operators. Here it seems that he provides a good solution, if the objects are unmutable.

However, I consider Sean Parents **statement** "polymorphic use cases of objects - having mutable objects - is the extreme extreme exception" **is wrong**.

Background:
[Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c/53795463#53795463)

Quote from "The Dilbert Principle":

> ENGINEER IDENTIFICATION GUIDE
>
> Self Assessment
>
> You walk into a room and notice that a picture is hanging crooked.
>
> You...
>
> **A**: Straighten it.
>
> **B**: Ignore it.
>
> **C**: Buy a CAD system
> and spend the next six months designing a solar-powered,
> self-adjusting picture frame
> while often stating aloud
> your belief that
> **the inventor of the nail was a total moron**.
>
> The correct answer is “C” but partial credit can be given to anybody who writes “It depends” in the margin of the test or simply blames the whole stupid thing on “Marketing.”

There is more statements in his video, where I do not agree with - for the same reason.