# C++ calling child function

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

How do I get the output of this code segment to print "Function of Child Class"?

I'm having trouble understanding why writing

```
BaseClass obj = DerivedClass();
```

causes a similar output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class BaseClass {
public:
   void disp(){
      cout<<"Function of Parent Class";
   }
   void dispOther(BaseClass& other) {
       other.disp();
   }
};
class DerivedClass: public BaseClass{
public:
   void disp() {
      cout<<"Function of Child Class";
   }
};

BaseClass getInstance() {
   BaseClass obj = DerivedClass();
   return obj;
}

int main() {
   auto obj = getInstance();
   auto obj2 = DerivedClass();
   obj2.dispOther(obj);
   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Function of Parent Class
```

Comment: Use pointers or references. Make the function virtual. Read a book on C++.

Comment: You should probably also read a bit about slicing.

Comment: [Here are some good C++ books for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392656/472974

Answer (score 2):

Object Slicing.  `obj` is a base class, even if it's being assigned from a derived class object.

To override functions in a derived class you need yo make the `disp()` function `virtual`, then try this:

```
DerivedClass d;
BaseClass& obj = d;

obj.disp();
```

Comment: Thank you! So taking d as a reference prevents losing the info then?

Comment: References (or pointers) to base classes can refer (or point) to derived objects.

Comment: You also need to make the `disp()` function virtual.

Comment: Given all your other provisos and edits, this would be the same as `d.disp();` I'm not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: The OPs leading question is "why does `BaseClass obj = DerivedClass ()` give the output he sees.  The two reasons are lack of `virtual` and object slicing.  Aside from rewriting all if the OPs code in this answer, I'm honestly not sure what else I could provide.