# overriding C++ not working as expected

Tags: c++, oop, overriding

I am new to object oriented programming , so I have a vague understanding of the overriding concept. However , the following example totally confuses me:

```
class Base {
  public:
    void Hello() {
      cout << "hello world from the BASE class" << endl;
    }

  void printHello() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      Hello();
    }
  }

};

class Derived: public Base {
  public: void Hello() {
    cout << "hello world from the DERIVED class";
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived obj;
  obj.printHello();
  return 0;
}
```

expected result: 5* "hello world from the DERIVED class"

result:  5* "hello world from the BASE class"

Shouln't the Hello() function in the BASE class be replaced by the one in the DERIVED class?  If not , how can I obtain this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use ``virtual`` keyboard in your ``Hello`` method

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: See [Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2391679/580083)

Comment: This issue is not about OOP in general, but more about how C++ implements polymorphism. I suggest you [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn about C++.