# How to store objects of multiple subclasses in a vector in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create any iterable to store subclass objects in.

I currently am using a vector of pointers to the superclass, but this doesn't seem to allow any of the subclass-specific declarations to be used.

```
class piece
{
public:
    int foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class pawn : public piece 
{
public:
    int foo()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

std::vector<piece*> pieces;
pieces.push_back(new pawn());

pieces[0]->foo(); // returns 1 though pieces[0] should be a pawn
```

The call to pieces[0]->foo() returns 1, when I want it to return 2.

Debugging shows that the "new pawn()" creates a piece pointer, so I get why it doesn't use the pawn function, but I don't know why it isn't a pawn in the first place.

Comment: You need to declare your `foo()` method as [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

Comment: This code does what you asked for, if you want polymorphism, you should Google for `virtual`

Comment: You might also want to read about [when to use `virtual` destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/1171191).

Comment: While the answer to your question may be obvious once you know it, this is definitely something that's hard to search for. You've done an awesome job of giving us a well written question of clean, concise code with your expected behavior and actual behavior. Great first question--I hope we see more from you in the future!

Comment: virtual is exactly what I needed. Coming from Python, there's so much nuance in C++ that I wouldn't know to look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `foo` method is not `virtual`. In several other object-oriented languages, all methods are "virtual" by default, but they are not in C++. "Virtual" means that the function to be called is determined at runtime. When you have a non-virtual method, the compiler decides at compile-time which function to call based on static type information.

In this case, since you have a vector of `piece`, the compiler invariably determines that it should call `pieces[0]->piece::foo()`, without checking if there is a more refined version of it in a subclass. If you have a virtual method, the compiler determines that it should look into the object to figure out which one to call based on its type. You would to change the declaration of `foo` in `piece` and `pawn`:

- `virtual int foo()` in `piece`;
- `virtual int foo() override` in `pawn`.

See "[Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c)". In the words of Kenneth Worden, "virtual allows the subclass method to be called, even if the object is being treated as its superclass".

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual

Comment: And you also need a virtual destructor in `piece`.