# Why the decorator pattern implementation requires a common abstract super-class with the core class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator

I'm experimenting with the decorator design pattern in `c++`. However, I was not able to implement it without an abstract super-class from which both the core and decorating classes inherit.

I don't understand why abstract super-class is needed.

My working decorator example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// abstract superclass
class Pizza
{
  public:
    virtual string GetDescription() = 0;
    virtual int GetCost() = 0;
};

// base class that can be extended
class Margharita: public Pizza 
{ 
   private:
    string description;
    int cost;
   public:
     Margharita(string t, int c){description = t; cost = c;} 
     string GetDescription(){return(description);}
     int GetCost(){return(cost);}
}; 

// decorator class that extends base class
class ExtraCheese: public Pizza
{
   private:
    Pizza* pizza;

   public:
    // constructor
    ExtraCheese(Pizza* p) {pizza = p;}

    string GetDescription() { return (pizza->GetDescription() + ", Extra Cheese"); } 
    int GetCost() {  return(pizza->GetCost() + 20); } 
};

int main()
{
  // create decorated object
  Pizza* pizza = new ExtraCheese(new Margharita("Margharita", 100));
  cout <<  pizza->GetDescription() << '\n';
  cout << pizza->GetCost() << '\n';
}
```

that gives the output: `Margharita, Extra Cheese 120`.

If I remove the abstract super-class, the decoration stops working:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// base class that can be extended
class Pizza
{
  private:
   string description;
   int cost;
  public:
    Pizza(){description = "Pizza"; cost = 100;};
    string GetDescription(){return(description);}
    int GetCost(){return(cost);}
}; 

// decorator class that extends base class
class ExtraCheese: public Pizza
{
   private:
    Pizza* pizza;

   public:
    // constructor
    ExtraCheese(Pizza* p) {pizza = p;}

    string GetDescription() { return (pizza->GetDescription() + ", Extra Cheese"); } 
    int GetCost() {  return(pizza->GetCost() + 20); } 
};

int main()
{
  // create decorated object
  Pizza* pizza = new ExtraCheese(new Pizza());
  cout <<  pizza->GetDescription() << '\n';
  cout << pizza->GetCost() << '\n';
}
```

In this case the output only shows the attributes of the core object (`Pizza 100`).

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: `GetDescription` isn't virtual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c)

Comment: This design exhibits several weirdnesses, in either case. "ExtraCheese" is not a pizza, yet it inherits from that class? Or if you say that "ExtraCheese" *is* a pizza, then why does it also contain a pizza? A better design would be to forgo inheritance completely and have Pizza simply contain a list of Toppings.

Comment: That's true. My development skills are still mainly limited to avoid compilation errors. However, I think that the decorator design principle is primarily about not changing code of core class when toppings changes, which is not case of your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you removed the abstract base class you made the function `GetDescription` and `GetCost` not virtual. As such they aren't dispatched dynamically. Which is why `pizza->GetDescription()` called the `Pizza` member function, it was a call resolved based on the *static type* of `pizza` only.

You don't need to have an abstract base to make it work again, only dynamic dispatch, so just add the virtual specifier

```
class Pizza
{
  private:
   string description;
   int cost;
  public:
    Pizza(){description = "Pizza"; cost = 100;};
    virtual string GetDescription(){return(description);}
    virtual  int GetCost(){return(cost);}
};
```

This will allow overriding in `ExtraCheese`, to be picked up by dynamic dispatch. You can also help the compiler catch such mistakes by employing the `override` specifier. Had you defined `ExtraCheese` like this:

```
class ExtraCheese: public Pizza
{
   private:
    Pizza* pizza;

   public:
    // constructor
    ExtraCheese(Pizza* p) {pizza = p;}

    string GetDescription() override { return (pizza->GetDescription() + ", Extra Cheese"); } 
    int GetCost() override {  return(pizza->GetCost() + 20); } 
};
```

A modern compiler would have complained you are trying to override a function that isn't declared virtual. The mistake would have been apparent.

Comment: g++ 8.1.0 with `-Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra` doesn't warn, if you override a function that isn't declared virtual.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler - Did you use the `override` specifier?

Comment: You are right, in the example there is `override`. In this case g++ reports an error.