# Method defined in superclass but implemented in subclass: accessing subclass attributes?

Tags: c++, class, oop, scope, visibility

Here's my class structure:

```
class Parent {
    public:
        void foo(); // foo() defined in superclass
};

class Child : public Parent {
    private:
        int bar;
    public:
        Child(int);
        int getBar();
};

Child::Child(int b) {
    bar = b;
}

void Child::foo() { // foo() implemented in subclass
    std::cout << getBar() << std::endl;
}
```

g++ gives me an error that `foo()` is not within `Child` scope, and changing it to `void Parent::foo()`, I'm left with an error that `getBar()` is not within `Parent` scope.

I'm aware of virtual functions but I do not want to define `foo()` in `Child`, only implement it.

How do I gain method visibility within `Child` of the `Parent` method `foo()`?

My thought process is the line `class Child : public Parent` means `Child` inherits member methods of `Parent`, thus `Child` should be able to see `foo()`.

Comment: Why can't you declare the methods in the class `Child` (not define them), as in, add the line `void foo()` under `public:` in the class `Child`? Then, you can go on to define the function under `void Child::foo()`.

Comment: @RealPawPaw then what is the point of a superclass for this example? Not trying to be short, just trying to understand super/subclass relationships. If it's defined in both the parent and child classes, there's no reason for it to be defined in the parent class.

Comment: You don't have to use them - it's just a feature. But you'll have to use the `virtual` keyword. Some uses of this are listed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c

Comment: Your question contains a contradiction: _"I do not want to define `foo()` in `Child`, only implement it"_ A function's implementation is its definition. So you do not want to define `foo()` in `Child`; instead you want to define `foo()` in `Child`. ??? Did you mean "declare" instead of "define"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong C++ terms: what you call "definition" is properly called "declaration", and what you call "implementation" is properly called "definition". Use correct terms to avoid confusion and misunderstanding.

So, if you define `Child::foo` you have to add corresponding declaration as well. I fixed it below.

Also look at the link RealPawPaw gave in his comment about when/why you should use `virtual`.

```
class Parent {
    public:
        /*virtual*/ void foo(); // this is declaration of Parent::foo
};

class Child : public Parent {
    private:
        int bar;
    public:
        Child(int); // this is declaration of constructor
        int getBar(); // this is declaration of Child::getBar
        void foo(); // this is declaration of Child::foo
};

// this is definition of Parent::foo
void Parent::foo() {
    std::cout << "Parent" << std::endl;
}

// this is definition of constructor
Child::Child(int b) {
    bar = b;
}

// this is definition of Child::getBar
int Child::getBar() {
    return bar;
}

// this is definition of Child::foo
void Child::foo() {
    std::cout << "Child: bar=" << getBar() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a prototype `void foo();` in the public section of Child class as well to tell you are using an inherited method. Then you can implement it like you did.

You are not able to access `getBar()` because you have not declared it. Declare it and it will work fine.