# Inheritance Class different between ' class a : b ' And ' class a : public b '

Tags: c++

I'm learning about C++ and I have a question.

I'm learning about virtual function, and I found saw [why do we need virtual functions in cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c/2392656#2392656).

I tried the answer and now I know why do we need virtual function, but I don't understand that,

below code works fine.

```cpp
class a
{
public:
    virtual void eat(){  std::cout<<"Eating A food." << endl;
};

class b : public a
{
public:
    void eat(){  std::cout<<"Eating B food." << endl;
}

void eatFunction(a * alpha){ alpha -> eat(); }

int main(void)
{
   a * apple = new a;
   b * banana = new b;

   eatFunction(apple);
   eatFunction(banana);
   return 0;
}
```

But I just changed `class b: public a` into `class b : a` error occured:

```
error: 'a' is an inaccessible base of 'b'
       eatFunction(banana);
```

When should I use 'public' inheritance parents class?

And what is different?

Comment: Your sample c ode is invalid.   There is no type named `apple` or `banana`, so the first two lines of `main()` need to be `a *apple = new a` and `b *banana = new b` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class b: public a{/*..*/};
```

`b` inherits from `a` publicly (i.e) all of the member functions and vars are inherited in `b` with the same access specifiers they have in `a`

```
class b: a{/*..*/};
```

`b` inherits from `a` privately (i.e) all of the member functions and vars are inherited in `b` with `private` access specifiers.
So you can't access your function `eatFunction` outside the class.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand, there is no any other advantanges using 'public' when I'm not going to make any other function outside of the parent class. So I don't need to use 'public' in the case, right? Of course it will be depends on what I'm going to do, I just wonder.

Answer (score 1):

```
class b : a {};
```

is the same as

```
class b : private a {};
```

Since `a` is a `private` base class of `b`, a `b*` cannot be implicitly converted to an `a*`.