# 'Circle::Area': 'override' specifier illegal on function definition Derektut

Tags: c++

My question is actual two fold. I am going through this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6y0bp-mnYU0 and at 1:07:45, he talks about using the override keyword when defining a virtual fucnction of an abstract class. I kept my classes declaration and definintion in different files. **When I try to use override in my definition, it gives me the "'override' specifier illegal" on function definition on Visual Studio 2019. Why is this?**

include "Circle.h"
include "Shape.h"

```
double Circle::Area() override {    
    return 3.14159 * pow((width / 2), 2);
}
```

**Also,  what does this code snippet do? I am new to c++:**

```
Circle::Circle(double width) : Shape(width) {

}
```

**Why is circle using a constructor from an abstract class? Is this even possible? What does the : Shape(width) do.**

This is what "Shape" class looks like:

```
class Shape
{
protected:  //means that inherited classes will be able to access as long as it is part of protected
    double height;
    double width;
public:

    static int numofShapes; 

    Shape(double length);
    Shape(double height, double width);
    Shape();
    Shape(const Shape& orig); 
    virtual ~Shape();

//Setters and getters for privat mems
void Setheight(double height);
double Getheight();
void Setwidth(double height);
double Getwidth();

static int Getnumofshapes();
virtual double Area() = 0; //makes it an abstract base class
```

// private: only class code

Comment: If the override is not needed since definition is outside of the declaration, how will the compiler know to properly override?

Comment: `Shape` is not abstract (it doesn't have any pure virtual functions) and it also doesn't have a `virtual double Area()` function you could `override`

Answer (score 0):

```
Circle::Circle(double width) : Shape(width) {

}
```

This code snippet is the implementation of the constructor of `Circle`. The stuff behind the `:` is the initializer list, which is used to initialize the data members of your class.

```
class A {
    public:
        A() : val1(1), val2(2) {

        }

    private:
        int val1;    // is initialized to 1
        int val2;    // is initialized to 2
}
```

In the initializer list, you not only have to initialize the fields, but you also have to call the constructor of the base class (in this case `Shape`) when the base class doesn't have a default constructor (constructor with no arguments). Therefore, as first element in the initializer list you have the name of the base class, and in parenthesis the parameters for `Shape`'s constructor.

---

You get an error that the override specifier is illegal, since you haven't declared a `virtual` function with the signature of your `Area`-function in the base class (`Shape`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c) stackoverflow post to learn how virtual functions work and for what they're used.

Comment: But I called Area virtual in my Shape class:  virtual double Area() = 0.

Comment: I have editted my original question to include the other functions. You will now see desigined Area() to be pure virtual function.  Also the Shape class does have a default constructor. Its in the original question. So I have a default constructor, why would I need to inherit the base class's constructor?

Comment: I have editted my original question to include the other functions. You will now see desigined Area() to be pure virtual function. Also the Shape class does have a default constructor. Its in the original question. So I have a default constructor, why would I need to inherit the base class's constructor @DasElias