# Why doesnt this function overide the base class function

Tags: c++, c++11

So here is the base class:

```
class MovieRepo {
protected:
    MyLista<Movie> all;
public:
    MovieRepo();
    void store(const Movie& m);
}
```

And this one is the override:

```
class RepoFile : public MovieRepo
{
private:
    string filename;
    void loadFromFile();
    void storeToFile();

public:

    RepoFile(string _filename) : filename{ _filename } { this->loadFromFile(); };

    void store(const Movie& m) override { // here is the error
        MovieRepo::store(m);
        storeToFile();
    }
}
```

It says:'RepoFile::store': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods

Comment: The message from `clang++` is a little more specific: _error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'_"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MovieRepo::store()` is not a virtual function. The `override` specifier only works with virtual functions. Change the base class method to a virtual method to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `override` keyword can *only* be used when the function it's overriding is `virtual`. (It is, effectively, just a 'safer' way of specifying `virtual` in a derived class, so that you can spot cases where there is no matching base-class function.)

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)

Fix: Either remove the `override` keyword (the base-class function will *still* be overriden) or add `virtual` to the base-class function).

Answer (score 0):

The *key* to the solution is the keyword [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

> The virtual specifier specifies that a non-static member function is virtual and supports dynamic dispatch. It may only appear in the decl-specifier-seq of the initial declaration of a non-static member function (i.e., when it is declared in the class definition).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c) for `why do we need virtual functions?`. With "virtual" we get "late binding". Which implementation of the method is used gets decided at run time based on the type of the pointed-to object - what it was originally constructed as (not on the type of the pointer that you call through!).

If you want such "late binding" and want to invoke the right method (*store*) at run-time irrespective of the type of the pointer that you use to call *store()*, then go ahead with virtual functions with the implementation below:

Try this:

```
class MovieRepo {
public:
    // ....
    virtual void store(const Movie& m);
}

class RepoFile: public MovieRepo {
public:
    void store(const Movie& m) override 
    { 
        // ....
    }
}
```

**More details on compilation warning/error:**

The [override](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword serves two purposes:

1. It shows the reader of the code that "this is a virtual method, that is overriding a virtual method of the base class."
2. The compiler also knows that it's an override, so it can "check" that you are not altering/adding new methods that you think are overrides.

In your case, compiler is warning you that the method your virtual function (in class `RepoFile`) isn't overriding any virtual function in base class.