# Storing the Derived Class objects in std::vector of Parent

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am creating a small project in c++ with the concept of inheritance and std::vector. I want to add my different clients in std::vector of Parent Class but when I call the run method, it always calls the Parent class run method not the child class run method.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class IClient
{
    public:
        void run(){std::cout<<"Base Client Called"<<std::endl;}

};

class AFKClient : public IClient
{
    public:
        void run() 
        {
            std::cout<<"AFK Client Called"<<std::endl;
            
        }
};

class Application
{
   public:
        std::vector<IClient> clients;
        void addClients(IClient client) 
        {
            clients.push_back(client);
        }

        void run() 
        {
            for (auto c: clients)
            {
                std::cout<<"calling client"<<std::endl;
                c.run();
            }
            
            
        }
};

int main()
{
    Application application;
    AFKClient afkClient;
    application.addClients(afkClient);
    application.run();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: well... try to read about `virtual` and you will know why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c

Comment: And even after you make `run` virtual, it still won't work due to [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). You need a container of (possibly smart) pointers to `IClient`, not `IClient` objects themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the definition of `Application` up a bit to support inheritance like you're expecting. Consider changing the vector to a vector of pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IClient>> clients;
```

Then you'll need to change the `addClients` method as well:

```
void addClients(std::unique_ptr<IClient> client) 
{
    clients.push_back(std::move(client));
}

// then call it later on like:
application.addClients(std::make_unique<AFKClient>(afkClient));
```

This will actually call the `virtual` functions that you want. Generally anytime you're dealing with inheritance you'll need to store pointers to the base class rather than the base class itself.