# TinyGSM c++ CRTP implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual, crtp

I am trying to understand the internals of https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/tree/master/src and am confused with how the classes are constructed.

In particular I see that in TinyGsmClientBG96.h they define a class that inherits from multiple templated parent classes.

```
class TinyGsmBG96 : public TinyGsmModem<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmGPRS<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmTCP<TinyGsmBG96, TINY_GSM_MUX_COUNT>,
                    public TinyGsmCalling<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmSMS<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmTime<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmGPS<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmBattery<TinyGsmBG96>,
                    public TinyGsmTemperature<TinyGsmBG96>
```

Fair enough. If I look at one of these, for example TinyGsmTemperature, I find some confusing code.

It looks like the static cast is in place so the we can call the hardware agnostic interface getTemperature() and use the implementation defined in TinyGsmBG96.

- Why not use function overriding in this case?
- What is the thinking behind this implementation?
- Is this a common pattern in c++?

```
template <class modemType>
class TinyGsmTemperature
{
public:
  /*
   * Temperature functions
   */
  float getTemperature()
  {
    return thisModem().getTemperatureImpl();
  }

  /*
   * CRTP Helper
   */
protected:
  inline const modemType &thisModem() const
  {
    return static_cast<const modemType &>(*this);
  }
  inline modemType &thisModem()
  {
    return static_cast<modemType &>(*this);
  }

  float getTemperatureImpl() TINY_GSM_ATTR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a common pattern in c++?

Yes, it is called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) - curiously recurring template pattern.

> Why not use function overriding in this case?

`override` relies on virtual tables, causing extra runtime overhead.

> What is the thinking behind this implementation?

Say, we want a class hierarchy with overridable methods. The classic OOP approach is `virtual` functions. However, they aren't zero-cost: when you have

```
void foo(Animal& pet) { pet.make_noise(); }
```

you don't statically know (in general) which implementation has been passed to `foo()` because you've erased its type from `Dog` (or `Cat`? or something else?) to `Animal`. So, the OOP approach uses virtual tables to find the right function at runtime.

How do we avoid this? We can instead remember the derived type statically:

```
template<typename Derived /* here's where we keep the type */> struct Animal {
    void make_noise() {
        // we statically know we're a Derived - no runtime dispatch!
        static_cast<Derived&>(*this).make_noise();
    }
};
struct Dog: public Animal<Dog /* here's how we "remember" the type */> {
    void make_noise() { std::cout << "Woof!"; }
};
```

Now, let's rewrite `foo()` in a zero-cost manner:

```
template<typename Derived> void foo(Animal<Derived>& pet) { pet.make_noise(); }
```

Unlike the first attempt, we haven't erased the type from `???` to `Animal`: we know `Animal<Derived>` is actually a `Derived`, which is a templated - therefore, fully known to the compiler - type. This turns the virtual function call into a direct one (so, even allows inlining).

Comment: more info on virtual functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c), also more info on CRTP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp). Fantastic answer thanks!