# C++ OOP inheritance, why this code couts "Data"

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Two classes: `Data` is parent and `DerivedData` is child. Why does `cout` output "Data"?

```cpp
class Data {
protected:
    int _value {};

public:
    Data(int value) : _value{ value } { }

    std::string getName() const { 
        return "Data"; 
    }

    int getValue() const { 
        return _value; 
    }

    void setValue(const int i) { 
        _value = i; 
    }
};

class DerivedData: public Data {
public:
    DerivedData(int value) : Data{ value } { }

    std::string getName() const { 
        return "DerivedData"; 
    }

    int getValueDoubled() const { 
        return _value * 2; 
    }
};
```

```cpp
DerivedData dd{ 5 };
Data d = dd;
Data& rd = dd;
cout << rd.getName() << endl;
```

This code will output "Data", but why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c)

Comment: You have forgotten that `virtual` is needed for functions to be polymorphic.

Comment: As a general tip: For each function you want to override in a child class, add the `override` identifier to mark it as such, and the compiler will tell you if the function actually overrides or not. As in `class DerivedData : public Data { public: ...; std::string getName() override const { return "DerivedData"; } ... };`

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `virtual` so it is kinda redefinition of the parent function which you think is polymorphsim but it is not.

When it execute this line of code `Data& rd = dd;` you had expected to be printed `DerviedData` but this did not happen because your function was not virtual, and base class do not know you are overriding the `getName` method in derived class.

So to fix this issue need to declare your function `virtual`:

```
virtual std::string getName() const { return "Data"; } //Data
```

And in DerivedData:

```
std::string getName() const override { return "DerivedData"; } //DerivedData
```

Now this will behave the way you'd expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the DerivedData class, you're not correctly calling the parent constructor. you will be calling the constructor as  "DerivedData(int value) : Data(value) {}".This small error in the syntax is causing the constructor of the Data class to not be called correctly when you create an object of the DerivedData class. As a result, the _name variable in the Data class remains uninitialized and contains a garbage value.

To fix this issue, you need to modify the DerivedData class definition as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Data {
protected:
    int _value{};

public:
    Data(int value) : _value{ value } {}

    string getName() const {
        return "Data";
    }

    int getValue() const {
        return _value;
    }

    void setValue(const int i) {
        _value = i;
    }
};

class DerivedData : public Data {
public:
    DerivedData(int value) : Data(value) {}

    string getName() const {
        return "DerivedData";
    }

    int getValueDoubled() const {
        return _value * 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    DerivedData dd(10);
    cout << dd.getName() << endl; // This will output "DerivedData"
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output will show DerivedData

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).