# Question regarding polymorphiic functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++ and currently I am studying polymorphism.

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
    public:
        void say_hello()
        {
            std::cout << "I am the base object" << std::endl;
        }
};


class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
        void say_hello()
        {
            std::cout << "I am the Derived object" << std::endl;
        }
};

void greetings(Base& obj)
{
    std::cout << "Hi there"<< std::endl;
    obj.say_hello();
}



int main(int argCount, char *args[])
{

    Base b;
    b.say_hello();

    Derived d;
    d.say_hello();

    greetings(b);

    greetings(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Where the output is:

```
I am the base object
I am the Derived object
Hi there
I am the base object
Hi there
I am the base object
```

This is not recognizing the polymorphic nature in the greetings functions.

If I put the `virtual` keyword in the `say_hello()` function, this appears to work as expected and outputs:

```
I am the base object
I am the Derived object
Hi there
I am the base object
Hi there
I am the Derived object
```

So my question is:
The polymorphic effect is retrieved when using a pointer/reference?

When I see tutorials they will present something like:

```
Base* ptr = new Derived();
greetings(*ptr);
```

And I was wondering if had to always resort to pointers when using polymorphism.

Sorry if this question is too basic.

Comment: You're almost there, just search around for "virtual functions in C++", you'll find lots of good guides.

Comment: Related topics that may help clarify a few things: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/11082165) and [Why do we need virtual functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2391679/11082165)

Comment: But am I correct in assuming that through references I get the polymorphic behavior correct?

Comment: @Brian. Slicing just means that only the "base" part of the object is collected/copied. Which means I only get Base type functions, no polymorphism. But if I use a reference or a pointer the slicing will get me the polymorphic part. Is this correct?

Comment: With a reference or pointer there is no copy. No copy, no slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polymorphic behavior you need 2 things:

- a virtual method overridden in a derived class
- an access to a derived object via a base class pointer or reference.

> ```
> Base* ptr = new Derived();
> ```

Those are bad tutorials. Never use owning raw pointers and explicit new/delete. Use smart pointers instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Currently I have not been taught about smart pointers. I just want to know if the polymorphic behavior can be obtained through a reference or if I must always have a pointer. If the first is not correct, why is my code showing the correct output

Comment: as I've said, pointers or references.

Comment: *"Use smart pointers instead."* Or just `Derived d; Base& b{d};` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a virtual declaration to the method to allow it to be overridden when using references to the base class:

```
virtual void say_hello() {...}
```

in both classes (or at least just the base class).