# Base class function being called instead of overridden function defined in Derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Here are my code

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class BaseClass
    {
    public:
        BaseClass() {}
        void init(const int object) { cout<<"BaseClass::init"<<endl; }
        void run(const int object) { cout<<"BaseClass::run calls =>";    init(object); }
    };
    
    class Derived : public BaseClass {
    public:
        Derived() {}
        void init(const int object) { cout<<"Derived::init"<<endl; }
    };
    
    int main() {
        BaseClass b;
        b.init('c');
        b.run('c');
    
    
        Derived d;
        d.init(5); // Calls Derived::init
        d.run(5);  // Calls Base::init. **I expected it to call Derived::init**
    }
```

And here is generated output

```
BaseClass::init
BaseClass::run calls =>BaseClass::init
Derived::init
BaseClass::run calls =>BaseClass::init
```

With call d.run(5), Why "BaseClass::init" is being called instead of "Derived::init" ?
I though we need virtual functions only when calling through a pointer.

**What is the rationale behind keeping such behavior ?**

Comment: You need to make `init` a `virtual` member function.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why "BaseClass::init" is being called instead of "Derived::init" ?

Because `init` is a **non-virtual member function**. To have the desired effect, you need to make `init` a **virtual member function** as shown below:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass() {}
    //NOTE THE VIRTUAL KEYWORD HERE
    virtual void init(const int object) { cout<<"BaseClass::init"<<endl; }
    //other member function here as before
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/73fIsUMYx)

---

> I though we need virtual functions only when calling through a pointer.

Note that the statement `init(object);` is **equivalent** to writing

```
this->init(object); //here `this` is a pointer
```

When you wrote:

```
d.run(5);
```

In the above statement, **first** the address of object `d` is **implicitly** passed as the first argument to the **implicit** `this` parameter of member function `run`. The type of this implicit `this` parameter is `BaseClass*` and this happens due to **derived to base conversion**. Now, the call `init(object);` is equivalent to `this->init(object);`. But since `init` is a **non-virtual** member function, the call is resolved at **compile time** meaning the base class `init` will be called.

Basically when a member function is called with a derived class object, the compiler first looks to see if that member exists in the derived class. If not, it begins walking up the *inheritance chain* and **checking** whether the member has been defined in any of the parent classes. It uses the first one it finds. This means for the call `d.run(5)` the search for a member function named `run` starts inside the derived class. But since there is no function named `run` inside derived class, the compiler looks into the direct base class `BaseClass` and finds the member function named `run`. So it stops its search and uses this found `run` member function. And as i said, in your example, `init` is non-virtual and so the call is resolved at compile time to the base class `run`.

On the other hand, if we make `init` to be a **virtual** member function, then this call will be resolved at **run-time** meaning the derived class `init` will be called.

Comment: " The type of this implicit this parameter is BaseClass* and this happens due to derived to base conversion" Why do we require this ? Doesn't Derived class also has run through inheritance ? so why does it require "derived to base conversion" ?

Comment: @ShaktiMalik It(derived to base conversion) happens automatically. For example, when you wrote `d.run(5)` the compiler tries to find a member function named `run` inside the derived class but since it can't find one, it looks into the direct base class `BaseClass` where it finds the function named `run` and so it stops looking further. And since it found the function in base class, it will resolve the call `d.run(5);` to this base class function.

Comment: @ShaktiMalik Basically when a member function is called with a derived class object, the compiler first looks to see if that member exists in the derived class. If not, it begins walking up the inheritance chain and checking whether the member has been defined in any of the parent classes. It uses the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

> I though we need virtual functions only when calling through a pointer.

No. Thats not right. You need to make a function virtual when you want to enable calling it based on the dynamic type of the object. And once you do have a virtual function you can use pointers or references to make use of the virtual dispatch.

You need to make a method virtual when you want to override it. As `BaseClass::run` is not overridden by `Derived::run`, there is no virtual dispatch and calling `init` from `BaseClass::run` calls `BaseClass::init`. If you want to enable virtual dispatch for `BaseClass::init` you need to declare it virtual.

Further, consider that your code is equivalent to:

```
void run(const int object) { 
    cout<<"BaseClass::run calls =>";    
    this->init(object); 
}
```

`this` is `BaseClass*`, hence `BaseClass::init` is called. You are calling `init` via a pointer, but that does not matter because `init` is not virtual. If you want to call `init` based on the dynamic type of the object, thats exactly what `virtual` is good for. The "overhead" you refer to in comments is not really overhead, but just the minimum needed to get the behavior you want. If you can change the design and do not need runtime polymorphism you can take a look at CRTP wich is a form of static polymorphism.

Comment: I can understand why we need to make a function virtual when calling using a base class pointer. But here we are using derived class Object which has information about "Derived::init" so this behavior is counter intuitive to me.

Comment: @ShaktiMalik there is no overriding in your code. I have seen bad tutorials where similar code is used to explain overriding, but it is not overriding. To override `init` it must be virtual. When you don't override it then calling `init` in `BaseClass` does call `BaseClass::init`

Comment: After this experiment I know that I need to make it virtual to make it work Which has associated overhead.  I wanted to get an answer to "What is the rationale behind keeping such behavior ?"

Comment: @ShaktiMalik the overhead you refer to is virtual dispatch, which would be the behaviour your want, not more. Its not "overhead" when thats just the functionality you desire. Its like saying "I want virtual dispatch without the overhead of virtual dispatch". Sorry, I don't understand what explaination you are looking for. Thats just how calling a non-virtual function works, what would be the rationale to use virtual dispatch on a non-virtual method?